# $PATH not being saved after I leave terminal

Tags: mysql, macos, terminal

I just installed mysql server 5.5.20 on my OS X Lion and everything works fine.Now,every time I go into terminal I have to explicitly write:

`PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin`

because is not being saved after I leave the command line.I have no idea why such could be.

Ideas?

Comment: I think you need to put it in your `.profile` or `.bash_profile` (if you do not have one create it in your home `~` directory) then from the command line do `. ~/.profile` or `. ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: didnt work for either `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` for me but worked in `~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You have to add

```
PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin
export PATH
```

to your `~/.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` (or use similar option when using different shell).

If you want it to be system wide, you should upgrade: `/etc/bash.bashrc` (on archilnux, can wary on your distribution)

Comment: @mvds yes, realized that just after I've posted answer... However it's different file on archilinux (it seems).

Comment: Yeah,that did it.I guess since I just got a Mac and I guess that a lot of issues like this will meet me.Thanks!----edit:adding the line to my .bash_profile was more than enough.

Comment: I'm using bash, and have both `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` files in my home directory, but for some reason it only works when I'm adding the line to `.bashrc`. Any idea why?

Comment: If you're on Mac, look for `.zprofile` on your home folder if you're using the default zsh instead of bash.

Comment: On Mac OS 10.15.7 (maybe later too?) you have to edit `/etc/paths` and add `/usr/local/mysql/bin` on a new line, then save and restart the Terminal.

Answer (score 20):

If anyone is using MacOs BigSur you should run  `open ~/.zshrc` ` and type the

`export PATH=`

In my case this was

`export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.3.24/bin/:$PATH`

Answer (score 7):

Then do not forget to run following command for bash to implement the current path without restarting:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

At the end you can try this command to check if path correctly implemented:

```
echo $PATH
```

it will show the content of your PATH, ideally you should find your new path there.

Answer (score 6):

edit your `~/.bash_profile`

and put the line:

`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin`

Answer (score 1):

I solved on my macOS High Sierra.

1. Open finder and go to path /Users/YOUR_USERNAME
2. Show hidden files with Shift + cmd + .
3. Create (if not exists) a file .profile
4. Write in this file export PATH=/YOUR PATH
5. Save this file.
   (If you have problem, try to create the file with sudo command)

Answer (score 0):

use `export PATH=/home/username/anaconda3/bin:$PATH` in terminal
and then type `anaconda-navigator.`
the app will be start instantly

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this recently on MacBooks with M1 chip. Exporting PATH variable did not work for me.

I found that the solution is already provided by homebrew. When you install homebrew, it suggests(on terminal) you to follow 'Next Step' in order to add it to profile. You just need to run those commands and you are done.

```
echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> /Users/{yourusername}/.zprofile
    eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

You can now restart the terminal and execute the command `brew help` to see if it works for you. Hopefully it helps someone.

Comment: My .zprofile already had `eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"`. Then too the problem existed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case .bash_profile had this lines at the end

```
export PATH
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin
```

That means homebrew installation just replaces all PATHs that was added in paths file by this last line. And my command in terminal $PATH always showed just /opt/homebrew/bin

I replaced these 2 line with 1 line

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/opt/homebrew/bin
```

and now $PATH in terminal shows whole bunch of paths