# How can I run Conda?

Tags: python, bash, anaconda, conda

I installed Anaconda and can run Python, so I assume that I installed it correctly. Following this [introductory documentation](http://docs.continuum.io/conda/intro.html), I am trying to install Python v3.3, so I am copying and pasting the following line into my console:

```bash
conda create -n py33 python=3.3 anaconda
```

However, that gives me an error:

> -bash: conda: command not found

What do I need to do to run Conda?

I am working on a Linux system.

Comment: After the Anaconda and Miniconda installs, there should have been a message like, "For this change to become active, you have to open a new terminal.".  Close the terminal and reconnect, and your command should work.

Comment: I had similar issue and @MacGyver advice has helped, but I just did it with 'source .bash_profile' from home directory.

Comment: @MacGyver You are so damn right!

Answer (score 81, accepted):

It turns out that I had not set the path.

To do so, I first had to edit [.bash_profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example) (I downloaded it to my local desktop to do that; I do not know how to text edit a file from Linux)

Then add this to .bash_profile:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/anaconda/bin
```

Comment: The anaconda installer usually does this for you, unless you explicitly tell it not to.

Comment: You may want to add `$HOME/anaconda/bin` to the front of your PATH, so that the Anaconda Python becomes your default Python.

Comment: @asmeurer The Anaconda installer does *not* do this for you, unless you explicitly tell it to.  The default is "no".

Comment: The default is no on Linux. It's yes on Windows and OS X.

Comment: Make sure to close and reopen your terminal after you modify your .bash_profile. I couldn't figure out why this wasn't working until I did so.

Comment: The comment of @Horatio nailed it! You Do have to close the terminal.

Comment: @asmeurer That's what I did with my Miniconda installation, but is it a good enough practice?

Comment: `Do you wish the installer to prepend the Anaconda2 install location
to PATH in your /home/hadoop/.bashrc ? [yes|no]
[no] >>>` @asmeurer

Answer (score 433):

You might want to try this:

**For Anaconda 2:**

```
export PATH=~/anaconda2/bin:$PATH
```

**For Anaconda 3:**

```
export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

**For Anaconda 4:**

Use the Anaconda Prompt.

And then

```
conda --version
```

to confirm that it worked.

The export *PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH* works, but it stops when you exit the terminal in order change that you have to run *sudo nano ~/.bashrc* and then copy the path into the file and save it  after that you activate the changes using *source .bashrc*.

Check with `conda install anaconda-navigator`. If not installed, follow the Anaconda install instructions again

Follow along with the video *https://youtu.be/Pr25JlaXhpc*.

Comment: or `export PATH=~/anaconda/bin:$PATH` where appropriate

Comment: When I type `export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH` into the terminal and then run `conda --version` it works fine. When I copy it into my .bashrc file, open terminal, and run `conda --version` it doesn't work. Any ideas why?

Comment: @NewNameStat: See this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127405/path-not-being-saved-after-i-leave-terminal

Comment: if I open a terminal and apply these changes, it works but if I close the terminal and reopen it, it again shows me the old python path not condo.
I tired it by removing all old path and still the same behavior.!!

Comment: I'm on elementaryOS (derived from Ubuntu 16.04). To update the PATH each time I login, I add PATH="$HOME/anaconda3/bin:$PATH" to ~/.profile

Comment: @Reihan_amnI have this problem too! Does anybody have some solution?

Comment: I have done the same thing. But it didn't work until I did "conda --version". Everything is working fine now

Comment: I've done the previous, and as I change the conda env, it (conda command) doesn't work, any idea?

Comment: **Note:** Doing this "manually" is discouraged. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55526573/11301900) shows the right solution.

Comment: @madcurie, may I know where can I find the video because the link is not working https://youtu.be/Pr25JlaXhpc?

Comment: The link is (effectively) broken: *"Video unavailable. This video is no longer available because the YouTube account associated with this video has been terminated."*

Answer (score 59):

## Use `conda init`

As pointed out in [a different answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54725966/570918), manually adding Conda on `$PATH` is no longer recommended as of v4.4.0 (see [Release Notes](https://github.com/conda/conda/releases/tag/4.4.0)).  Furthermore, since [Conda v4.6](https://github.com/conda/conda/releases/tag/4.6.0) new functionality to manage shell initialization via the `conda init` command was introduced.  Hence, the updated recommendation is to run

**Linux/UNIX and OS X before [macOS v10.15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Catalina) (Catalina)**

```
./anaconda3/bin/conda init
```

**Mac OS X v10.15 (Catalina) and later**

```
./anaconda3/bin/conda init zsh
```

**Windows**

```
./anaconda3/Scripts/conda.exe init
```

You must launch a new shell or source your init file (e.g., `source .bashrc`) for the changes to take effect.

**Details.** For an in-depth look at exactly what `conda init` does see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69024715/570918).

---

#### Alternative shells

You may need to explicitly identify your shell to Conda. For example, if you run `zsh` (Mac OS X 10.15+ default) instead of `bash` then you would run

```
./anaconda3/bin/conda init zsh
```

Please see `./anaconda3/bin/conda init --help` for a comprehensive list of supported shells.

---

#### Word of Caution

I'd recommend running the above command with a `--dry-run|-d` flag and a verbosity (`-v`) flag, in order to see exactly what it would do. If you don't already have a Conda-managed section in your shell run commands file (e.g., `.bashrc`), then this should appear like a straight-forward insertion of some new lines. If it isn't such a straightforward insertion, I'd recommend clearing any previous Conda sections from `$PATH` and the relevant shell initialization files (e.g., `bashrc`) first.

Again, for those interested, there is an in-depth look at how it works, [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69024715/570918).

---

### Potential Automated Cleanup

Conda v4.6.9 introduced a `--reverse` flag that automates removing the changes that are inserted by `conda init`.

Comment: is there a .bashrc on windows 10?

Comment: @johnktejik it all depends on the shell you're running. When you run `conda init` with the verbose flag `-vv` it will tell you exactly what it's going to edit.

Comment: `conda init` overwrites both your `C:\Users\<name>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1` and `C:\Users\<name>\Documents\PowerShell\profile.ps1`.

Comment: @not2qubit have you reported that on GitHub Issues? That doesn't seem like something they would be doing intentionally.

Comment: It's been [repeatedly](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues?q=is%3Aissue+profile.ps1) reported, opened and closed.

Comment: @not2qubit thanks for pointing that out. Do you think we should add a warning directly in the answer? Also, does running with `--dry-run` correctly show what it would change?

Answer (score 27):

If you have installed [Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)), but you are not able to load the correct versions of Python and [IPython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython), or if you see *"conda: command not found"* when trying to use Conda, this may be an issue with your PATH environment variable. At the prompt, type:

```
export PATH=~/anaconda/bin:$PATH
```

[For this example](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/faq.html), it is assumed that Anaconda is installed in the default `~/anaconda` location.

Comment: This simply recapitulates earlier answers (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/18675970/570918).

Answer (score 27):

This information is current as of 2016-08-10. Here are the exact steps I took to fix this using methods posted above. I did not see anyone post: `export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/anaconda/bin` (you need to add export to the beginning of the line).

Here it is, step-by-step:

For anyone running into the same problem while using [Oh My Zsh](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh), you need to do the following:

- Open your `.zshrc` in your terminal. I am using [iTerm 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITerm2) and have [Sublime Text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text) 3 as my default text editor:

  `subl ~/.zshrc`
- Once the file opens in your text editor, scroll to the very bottom and add:

  `export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/anaconda/bin`
- Save the file, then close it.
- Close your terminal, then relaunch it.
- Once back in your terminal, type:

  `conda --v`

  You should then see the version of `conda` installed printed on your screen.

---

If you're using [Z shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) (executable `zsh`), then after doing that, your terminal may show you `zsh: command not found: rvm-prompt`.

The solution is:

1. add `alias rvm-prompt=$HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm-prompt` within `.zshrc` file.
2. type `source .zshrc`.

Then the `zsh: command not found: rvm-prompt` will disappear.

Comment: Thanks, it works now. I wonder why putting PATH in .bash_profile doesn't work.

Comment: Worked!, Expect I had to add 3 to the export path. export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/anaconda3/bin

Comment: For me what worked is adding `export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/opt/anaconda3/bin` to the end of the zsh file

Answer (score 27):

My environment: macOS and Anaconda 3

This works for me:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Add this:

```
export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

The export path must match with the actual path of executable `anaconda3` in the system.

Exit out and run:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Then try:

```
jupyter notebook
```

Comment: This is the answer that worked for me. Crucial step was running  `$ source ~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: this worked for me thanks. I added export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH on line 3, after the other PATH definition

Answer (score 23):

Edit [~/.bash_profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example), and add this to it.

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/anaconda/bin
```

Then run

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: Thanks for this, this line also works for an oh-my-zsh profile where some of the other lines do not.

Comment: This merely recapitulates earlier answers (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/18675970/570918)

Comment: in my ~/.bash_profile there were already lines on anaconda2 and anaconda3 (probably result of the installation). I just had to run the second part of the answer `source ~/.bashprofile` (also for my macOSX Catelina zsh terminal)

Answer (score 16):

I'm on [macOS v10.13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_High_Sierra) (High Sierra) and just installed Anaconda 3 via a [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager)) command. I had an issue with running:

```
conda
```

It'd also give me:

> -bash: conda: command not found

I tried running:

```
export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

But it needs *entire* path. So here are the correct steps:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Now export the *entire* path. In my case it was:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

Exit out and run:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Then try:

```
conda
```

For example,

```
conda --version
```

Output:

```
conda 4.4.10
```

Comment: This works but once I close the terminal and re-open the I have to source it again

Comment: @mjwrazor Under MacOS, use ~/.bashrc instead of ~/.bash_profile.

Comment: At least in the Galapagos, they know where things are located!!! Wish I could add some stars.

Answer (score 11):

If you have just installed Anaconda and got this error, then I think you forgot to run this command:

- `source ~/.bashrc`

This will enable you to make use of Anaconda in terminal.

This may seems simple, but many (including me) do this mistake.

If the error is still persisting, you have to verify if anaconda location is added to PATH in your system.

Once you add it, you'll be fine.

Comment: the latest installer says it is not recommended to add conda to the PATH

Answer (score 8):

If you have installed Anaconda and have definitely said `yes` to the:

> Do you wish the installer to prepend the Anaconda install location to PATH in your /home/name/.bashrc ? [yes¦no]

question then you maybe just need to restart your terminal window. The change won't take effect until you either (1) close and reopen the current window or (2) just open and start working in a new window

Basically, open a new console window and see if it works now.

Comment: For me, all I had to do was restart the terminal and the conda command started working. ^^Underrated answer.

Comment: I think this "answer" would be more appropriate as a comment. The question and answers here have to do with Anaconda installation, not terminal basics. Restarting the terminal is a good reminder, but it's not an answer to this question.

Comment: Who cares? They had a problem which they were trying to solve and for some people (me included) this fixed the problem. Thus it is an "answer".

Answer (score 8):

For Windows:

A recent Anaconda (version 4.4.0) changed some directories.
You can find "conda" in Anaconda3/**Scripts**, instead of Anaconda3/bin.

Answer (score 6):

Mostly, it is because when we install Anaconda in the end, it adds the Anaconda path to PATH variable in the [.bashrc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example) file.

So we just need to restart the terminal or just do:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

If still it doesn't work, then follow these commands:

```
cat >> ~/.bashrc
```

Paste the below command for Anaconda 3:

```
export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>.

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: @johnktejik Which Linux distribution are you using?

Answer (score 4):

Using the `export PATH=` strategy with `conda activate` will result into a warning message for Conda 4.4 or later.

The recommended way (see this [release note](https://github.com/conda/conda/releases/tag/4.4.0), and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47246350/conda-activate-not-working)) to do it is to remove the `export PATH=...` line and instead add the following line in your [.bashrc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example) (or [`.bash_profile`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example)) file:

```
. ~/anaconda2/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
```

Furthermore, if you want Conda to be activated by default, add:

```
conda activate
```

Comment: how do I get rid of the "(base)" in front of the command line?

Comment: This is the best way to not modify PATH directly and let conda handle it.

Answer (score 3):

If you have installed [Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)), but if you are not able to execute a Conda command from the terminal, it means the path is probably not set, try:

```
export PATH=~/anaconda/bin:$PATH
```

See [this link](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/faq.html).

Comment: cool !, it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I also was facing the same issue. This might be the simplest possible solution:

```
source anaconda/bin/activate
```

For Anaconda 2, use

```
source anaconda2/bin/activate
```

Depending on the name of the directory, then execute your command, i.e., `conda --create`.

Comment: if that didnt help , try restarting , after that try " source ~/.bashrc", then try ur command. hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Run

```
cat ~/.bash_profile
```

to check if Anaconda is there. If not, you should add its path there.
If Conda is there, copy the entire row that you see the Anaconda there from "export" to the end of line.

Like this:

```
export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

Run this in your terminal.

Then run

```
conda --version
```

to see if it is exported and running!

Comment: It is partly incomprehensible near *"that you see the Anaconda there"*. Can you fix it?

Answer (score 2):

System: macOS

I installed Anaconda first, and everything worked well. Then I installed [iTerm2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITerm2) and when I typed `Python`, iTerm2 gave me the default Python. Here is how to find your Anaconda Python back:

1. Open your [`.zshrc`](https://wiki.debian.org/Zsh#Configuration) file. For example, `vim ~/.zshrc`
2. Then add `export PATH="/Users/yourusername/anaconda2/bin:$PATH"` to the last line of the file. Note that you need to replace the `yourusername` to your user name and make sure you have anaconda2. An easy way is to copy this line from [`~/.bash_profile`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example).
3. Save the file, close it, relaunch the terminal and now Anaconda Python should be back.

Answer (score 2):

**Answer for**

- Anaconda 3 5.2.0 installer
- [macOS v10.13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_High_Sierra) (High Sierra)
- [Z shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell)

---

1. Unfortunately, the installer puts the PATH definition only into [.bash_profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example), but not the [.zshrc](https://wiki.debian.org/Zsh#Configuration) configuration.
2. Contrary to the given answers, it doesn't (necessarily) install in `~/anaconda3/`, but **instead** in `/anaconda3/`.

---

The `PATH` defintion in file *.zshrc* must therefore be this:

```
...
# Anaconda3
export PATH="/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
...
```

Comment: The right way of doing this is to first run `source <path to conda>/bin/activate`, then `conda init zsh`.

Answer (score 1):

Temporary solution:

```
$anaconda/bin/conda create -n py33 python=3.3 anaconda
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have just installed [Miniconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)) or Anaconda make sure you rerun your terminal.

From this, I mean close and open your terminal and then try **conda list** to verify your installation.

For me, this worked!!

Comment: This essentially recapitulates an earlier answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39378909/570918

Answer (score 1):

To edit [.bashrc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example) in Ubuntu:

```
/usr/bin/vim ~/.bashrc
```

Type `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/anaconda3/bin`.

Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> and `:wq` to save the *.bashrc* file and exit Vim.

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHfTL.png)

Then

```
export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

And type `source ~/.bashrc`.

Now to confirm the installation of Conda, type

```
conda --version
```

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51619519/edit) (it covers answers as well). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Open your terminal and type the following command to add Anaconda to environment path.

For Anaconda 2:

```
export PATH=~/anaconda2/bin:$PATH
```

For Anaconda 3:

```
export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

Then, to check the Conda version, just type,

```
conda --version
```

Create an environment using the following command,

```
conda create --name myenv
```

Activate the source using,

```
source activate myenv
```

Then your Anaconda IDE is ready!

Answer (score 1):

If you installed Anaconda with Visual Studio 2017 for Windows,
conda executable is in this path or similar.

In my case path is this:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\Scripts`

Steps to add it to your PATH:

- On the Windows desktop, right-click My Computer.
- In the pop-up menu, click Properties.
- In the System Properties window, click the Advanced tab, and then click Environment Variables.
- In the System Variables window, highlight Path, and click Edit.
- Add your path and restart your cmd.

You will be able to execute `conda`

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the Conda path was properly set (in [.bashrc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example)) by the Conda installation Bash script. But to make it works I had to give  executable file permissions to files in bin sub folder with `chmod +x *`.

My system information:

- Conda 4.2.9
- Operating System: Debian 8 GNU/Linux 8 ([Jessie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history#Debian_8_(Jessie)))
- Kernel: Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64
- Architecture: x86-64

Answer (score 0):

I am setting up a virtual machine running Ubuntu. I have Anaconda 3 installed in the "Home" folder.  When I typed "conda" into the terminal I was getting the error "conda: command not found" too.

Typing the code below into the terminal worked for me...

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/anaconda3/bin
```

to check it worked I typed:

```
conda --version
```

which responded with the version number.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put Anaconda.sh to your */home/<your_name_file>*, and then run it to install. After that, you can run`export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH`. Remark: do not run *Anaconda.sh* in *download/* directly!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I removed the Anaconda directory from the install location and reinstalled.
After that, it worked as I anticipated.

Answer (score 0):

First, check the location of Anaconda. For me, I installed Anaconda 3 at the `/` directory which I access with `/anaconda3`.

Then in your terminal, input `export PATH="<base location>/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"`. For me, it's `export PATH="/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"`.

Finally, input `source $/anaconda3/bin/activate`. For you, just change to your location.

Now, you could try `conda list` to test.

Also, visit [the installation guide](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/macos.html#install-macos-silent).

Answer (score 0):

1. Check where you have installed Anaconda. In my case it looks like `/home/nour/anaconda3/bin`
2. Open your `.bashrc` file. For example, `gedit .bashrc`
3. Add this `export PATH = /home/nour/anaconda3/bin:$PATH` line at the end of the file and save.
4. Reopen the terminal. Type `conda --version`

**Note:** Make sure the path in *1.* and *3.* are the same. In my case, `/home/nour/anaconda3/bin`.

Answer (score 0):

The main point is that, as of December 2018, it's `Scripts`, not `bin`.

#### Updating $PATH in Git Bash for Windows

Use one of these:
`export PATH=$USERPROFILE/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda2/Scripts/:$PATH`
`export PATH=$USERPROFILE/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/Scripts/:$PATH`

#### Updating $PATH in the Windows default command line

Use one of these:
`SET PATH=%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\Scripts\;%PATH%`
`SET PATH=%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\;%PATH%`

#### Updating $PATH in Linux

Change `/app` to your installation location. If you installed Anaconda change `Miniconda` to `Anaconda`. Also, check for *Script* vs. *bin*,

`export PATH="/app/Miniconda/bin:$PATH"`

You may need to run `set -a` before setting the path, I think this is important if you're setting the path in a script.  For example if you have your export command in a file called `set_my_path.sh`, I *think* you'd need to do `set -a; source("set_my_path.sh")`.

The `set -a` will make your changes to the path persist for your session, but they are still not permanent.

For a more permanent solution add the command to `~/.bashrc`.  The installers may offer to add something like this to your `~/.bashrc` file, but you can do it too (or comment it out to undo it).

#### General Observations:

Background: I installed the 64-bit versions of Anaconda 2 and 3 recently on my [Windows 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10) machine following the recommended installation steps in December of 2018.

- Adding Conda also enables [IPython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython), which works much better in the native Windows command line
- Following the *strongly recommended* installation does not add Conda or IPython to the path
- Anaconda 3 doesn't seem to install a command prompt application, but Anaconda 2 did have a command prompt application
- The `/bin` folder seems to have been replaced with `Scripts`
- Poking around in the *Scripts* folder is interesting, maybe the Anaconda command prompt application is in there somewhere.

Comment: the latest installer says it is not recommended to add conda to the PATH

Answer (score -1):

For Windows:

```
PATH=%USERPROFILE%\Continuum\Anaconda4.4.0\Library\bin;%PATH%
```

Answer (score -1):

Type `anaconda-navigator` in the terminal.

Then the Anaconda application will be start.

Answer (score -1):

Similar to the above, remember that you could have [Miniconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)) instead of Conda, so you might want to add

`export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/davidfortini/miniconda3/bin` to [`.zshrc`](https://wiki.debian.org/Zsh#Configuration) or [`.bash_profile`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example) and then reboot the terminal.