# why use brew to install anaconda on mac os

Tags: macos, anaconda, homebrew

I need to install anaconda on my new mac.

There are two options. One using brew (`brew install --cask anaconda`) and the other via the [official anaconda installer](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/mac-os/)

Why should I use which?
I read about problems using brew and conda e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33156755/brew-command-not-found-after-installing-anaconda-python)
So why not always using the official installer? Why is there the brew option?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Home brew is a package manager which automates each and everything to get your required software being installed through it including not only the dependencies but also automatically getting the newer versions. Moreover it mainly becomes helpful when we need to uninstall such software which have dependent libraries installed, it helps in removing them safely also.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. So you basically suggest to always use brew instead of the original source for mac?

Comment: I suggest to use it if whatever you are trying to install or uninstall have some dependencies. Actually it's about the developer's perceptive, command line is considered to be more efficient. Otherwise original source works perfectly too.