# Conda command not found

Tags: python, zsh, anaconda, miniconda

I've installed [Miniconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)) and have added the environment variable `export PATH="/home/username/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"` to my *[.bashrc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example)* and *[.bash_profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example)*, but still can't run any Conda commands in my terminal.

Am I missing another step in my setup? I'm using [Z shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) (executable `zsh`) by the way.

Comment: Did you try with full path `/home/username/miniconda3/bin/conda`?

Comment: And your `zsh` is set up to read `.bashrc` (I doubt it, it's called `._bash_rc` for a reason)? By default `zsh` reads `.zprofile` and `.zshrc`, instead (plus `.zlogin` for login shells).

Comment: I've tried the full path /home/username/miniconda3/bin/conda. Unfortunately, it didn't work.

Comment: @dhke It is set up to read .bashrc. I have no issue with RVM

Comment: @olivrg Nevermind then. Did the full path invocation return an error message?

Comment: It didn't return any errors.

Comment: @dhke you were right. I wasn't set up to read the .bashrc.  It's working now after adding the environment variable to .zshrc as you suggested. Cheers mate!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run Conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675907/how-to-run-conda)

Comment: why isn't this already in my path? Why do I need to manually add it? :/

Answer (score 315, accepted):

If you're using zsh and it has not been set up to read .bashrc, you need to add the Miniconda directory to the zsh shell PATH environment variable. Add this to your `.zshrc`:

```
export PATH="/home/username/miniconda/bin:$PATH"
```

Make sure to **replace** `/home/username/miniconda` with **your actual path**.

Save, exit the terminal and then reopen the terminal. `conda` command should work.

Comment: Instead of exiting and reopening, Using `source ~/.zshrc` will do

Comment: I tried this, but I still get an error when trying to install stuff `CondaIOError: Missing write permissions in: /anaconda`

Comment: It works! But the path has a slight difference. `export PATH="/Users/victorzhang/anaconda2/bin:$PATH"`, the path beginning is `/Users/`, instead of `/home/`      still thank you @olivrg

Comment: For those who don't know: copy the command in the `.zshrc` file that will be located in your `/User/<yourusername>/` directory.

Comment: My binary was in condabin at in /usr/local/anaconda3--it's 2021 and I'm on a Mac. I added condabin to the path in .zshrc at /User/<yourusername>/ and it worked.

Comment: ```nano ~/.bashrc``` - then in the end add  ```export PATH="/home/username/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"``` 
Make check if its miniconda or miniconda3 ```source ~./.bashrc```

Comment: where is `.zshrc`? Is it a mac thing?

Comment: `.zshrc` is the configuration file. You can open it with your text editor using this command: `nano ~/.zshrc`

Comment: why isn't this already in my path? Why do I need to manually add it? :/

Comment: After adding conda path to the $PATH inside .bashrc, and running `source .bashrc`; you may also need to run `conda init`

Comment: It is enough to do `conda init zsh` to setup conda for Z shell.

Answer (score 99):

If you have the PATH in your .bashrc file and are still getting

```
conda: command not found
```

Your terminal might not be looking for the Bash file.

Type
`bash` in the terminal to ensure you are in Bash and then try:

`conda --version`

Comment: thanks for this! But what is the reason we have to type bash?

Comment: im not 100% sure but I think it's to let your command prompt read the bashrc file

Comment: Yes, the start script for conda was added inside your .bashrc file during installation, so you need to start bash shell to start the conda

Comment: why isn't this already in my path? Why do I need to manually add it? :/

Comment: when you installed conda you might have select NO to add to path since it's the default.

Comment: conda install with homeberw in mac need this command to export path 
    export PATH="/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"

Answer (score 53):

Maybe you need to execute "source ~/.bashrc"

Comment: Can you explain what does this command actually do? Thanks!

Comment: @KaranSharma I believe it resets the environment variables for your profile. If you recently installed Anaconda, that file was edited by the installer with the new env variables, but have not been loaded for conda or other utilities.
I might be wrong, I'm new to this whole thing.

Comment: @Karan Sharma: The mysterious "[sourcing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_(command)#Source)" explained

Answer (score 42):

Sometimes, if you don't restart your terminal after you have also installed Anaconda, it gives this error.

Close your terminal window and restart it.

It worked for me now!

Comment: Also instead of close/open terminal, could `source ~/.bashrc` OR `. ~/.barshrc` if bash is a shell you are using (to see your shell `echo $0`)

Answer (score 42):

To initialize your shell, run the below code:

```
source ~/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda activate Your_env
```

It worked for me. I got the solution from the below link
[https://www.codegrepper.com/code-[“CommandNotFoundError](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-%5B%E2%80%9CCommandNotFoundError): Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.][1]examples/shell/CommandNotFoundError%3A+Your+shell+has+not+been+properly+configured+to+use+%27conda+activate%27.+To+initialize+your+shell%2C+run

Comment: Don't forget to replace anaconda3 with miniconda3 if you're using miniconda.

Comment: This works only on current terminal

Comment: That is some completely messed up link! Can you [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64815977/edit) it? (But *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***without*** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***  "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today)

Answer (score 34):

For those experiencing issues after upgrading to [macOS v10.15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Catalina) (Catalina).

Short version:

```
# 1a) Use tool: conda-prefix-replacement -
# Restores: Desktop -> Relocated Items -> Security -> anaconda3
curl -L https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/misc/cpr-exec/cpr-0.1.1-osx-64.exe -o cpr && chmod +x cpr
./cpr rehome ~/anaconda3
# or if fails
#./cpr rehome ~/anaconda3 --old-prefix /Anaconda3
source ~/anaconda3/bin/activate

# 1b) Alternatively - reinstall Anaconda -
# brew cask install anaconda

# 2) conda init
conda init zsh
# or
# conda init
```

Further reading - [Anaconda blog post](https://www.anaconda.com/how-to-restore-anaconda-after-macos-catalina-update/) and [GitHub discussion](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/10998).

Answer (score 21):

**conda: command not found**

Try adding the below line to your .bashrc file:

```
export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

Then try:

```
conda --version
```

to see the version.

And then for it to take effect

```
conda init
```

Answer (score 18):

Maybe you should type add this to your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`

```sh
export PATH="/anaconda3/bin":$PATH
```

It worked for me.

Comment: On ubuntu i needed to refer to home so i used: `export PATH="~/anaconda3/bin":$PATH` and it worked

Comment: `echo $0` to see what shell if it is `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` OR `ls -ld ~/.*` to see which one is already there.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using Mac and have installed Conda with Homebrew then you need to run this command to export the path:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/bin"
```

Answer (score 8):

Execute the following command after installing and adding to the path

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

where `source` is a bash shell built-in command that executes the content of the file passed as argument, in the current shell.

It runs during boot up automatically.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. I just closed and reopened the terminal, and it worked. That was because I installed Anaconda with the terminal open.

Answer (score 4):

I faced this issue on my Mac after updating Conda. The solution was to run the Conda mini installer on top of the existing Conda setup.

```
curl https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-MacOSX-x86_64.sh -o ~/miniconda3.sh
bash ~/miniconda3.sh -bfp ~/miniconda3
```

On Linux, you can use:

```
curl https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -o ~/miniconda3.sh
bash ~/miniconda3.sh -bfp ~/miniconda3
```

For other versions, you can go to https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/

For details, check:
*[Conda command not found after running conda update package #1364](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/1364)*

Answer (score 3):

I had to run the following command to activate the shell:

```
eval "$(/home/username/anaconda3/bin/conda shell.bash hook)"
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Linux:

After installing Anaconda from the *.sh* file (which you can download from https://www.spyder-ide.org/):

Step 1:
Activate the environment in the terminal by entering the below command.

```
source ~/anaconda3/bin/activate
```

Step 2:

Type *spyder* in the terminal. You can get the Spyder IDE.

```
spyder
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you are installing the Anaconda binary that is compatible with your kernel.

I was in the same situation. It turned out I have an x64_86 CPU and was trying to install a 64-bit [POWER8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POWER8) installer. You can find out the same for your CPU by using the following command. It gives you a basic information about a computer's software and hardware.

```
uname -a
```

https://www.anaconda.com/download/#linux

The page in the link above displays two different types of 64-bit installers:

- 64-bit (x86) installer and
- 64-bit (POWER8) installer.

Answer (score 2):

export PATH="~/anaconda3/bin":$PATH

Comment: That is a bit terse. In what context? Where should it be applied?

Answer (score 1):

The brute-force way could be

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/root/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/root/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/root/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
```

Then initialize and test Conda.

```
conda init
conda -V
```

Which is what Conda tries to do. Take a look at the end of `~/.bashrc` with `less ~/.bashrc` or with `cat ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 1):

Do the same thing as the suggestion given by bash console, but pay attention that there are some errors in the suggestion (the file path format is incorrect). Paste these two commands in the Bash console for Windows:

```
echo ". C:/Users/mingm/Anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" >> ~/.bashrc
```

and

```
echo "conda activate" >> ~/.bashrc
```

After having pasted these two commands, exit the Bash console, reload it and then activate the virtual environment by entering "conda activate your_env_name".

Answer (score 1):

It can be a silly mistake. Make sure that you use `anaconda3` instead of `anaconda` in the export path if you installed it so.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Anaconda and Miniconda will put necessary command alias to the [.bashrc file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example) file.

All you have to do is to reload added alias inside `~/.bashrc` using this command:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: This works. Alternatively, if you are using zsh, you need to source ~/.zshrc

Answer (score 1):

I am using a [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) system.

In my case, for the *conda* command to be added to the path, and persist, I had to do the following:

#### First:

```
vim ~/.bashrc
```

This will open the .bashrc file using [Vim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29). You should go to the bottom of the file using the arrow keys, click `i` to toggle the insert mode and paste: `export PATH="$PATH:/home/userName/miniconda3/bin"`.

After that, save and close Vim using <kbd>:wq</kbd>.

(if you are not comfortable using Vim, you can use the `nano` command instead)

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

#### Second:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

#### Third:

Close and open the terminal! This should work for everyone.

To test if it is working, try:

```
conda --version
```

Answer (score 0):

For Conda > 4.4 follow this:

```
echo ". /home/ubuntu/miniconda2/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Then you need to reload user bash, so you need to log out:

```
exit
```

And then log again.

Comment: What do you mean by *"reload user bash"*? Reload the content of file *.bashrc*? Or something to do with file `/usr/bash`? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on CentOS and miniconda3. Find out which shell you are using

`echo $0`

`conda init bash` (could be `conda init zsh` if you are using `zsh`, etc.) - this adds a path to `~/.bashrc`

Reload command line

`sourc ~/.bashrc` OR `. ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem lately and I have found a solution that worked for me. It is possible that your current user might not have permissions to anaconda directory, so check if you can read/write there, and if not, then change the files owner by using `chown`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked on an [M1 Mac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_M1):

To get the user name:

```
echo $USER
```

Then substitute my_username with the correct one.

```
source /Users/my_username/opt/anaconda3/bin/activate
```

Answer (score 0):

For me uninstalling and reinstalling miniconda did the trick. I did lose all my existing repos but at least the command works now.

Answer (score -1):

Mac OS X: `cd /Users/USER_NAME/anaconda3/bin && ./activate`

Answer (score -1):

on conda prompt try

```
conda init powershell
```

Answer (score -1):

To add Anaconda to your system's PATH as well as User PATH on Windows, you can follow these steps:

1. **Find Anaconda Installation Directory**: The Anaconda installation directory will typically be something like `C:\Users\<YourUsername>\Anaconda3` or `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3`, depending on whether it's installed for a specific user or for all users.
2. **Open System Properties**:

   - Right-click on the **Start** button and select **System**.
   - Click on **Advanced system settings** on the left-hand side.
3. **Environment Variables**:

   - In the System Properties window, click the **Environment Variables** button at the bottom.
4. **Edit System Variables**:

   - Under the "System Variables" section, find the `Path` variable and select it.
   - Click the **Edit** button.
5. **Add Anaconda Path**:

   - Click the **New** button and add the path to the Anaconda installation directory. For example: `C:\Users\<YourUsername>\Anaconda3` or `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3`.
6. **Save and Apply Changes**:

   - After adding the Anaconda path, click **OK** to close each of the open windows.
   - Repeat step 4,5 and 6 for adding the path to User PATH as well
7. **Restart Command Prompt**:

   - If you have a Command Prompt or PowerShell open, close and reopen it for the changes to take effect.
8. **Verify Installation**:

   - Open a new Command Prompt or PowerShell window.
   - Type `conda --version` and press Enter. This should display the version of Conda if the PATH configuration was successful.

Remember to replace `<YourUsername>` with your actual Windows username and adjust the installation path if you installed Anaconda in a different location.