# Anaconda Python 3.6 install issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, anaconda, zsh

I uninstalled Anaconda 3 installation on my mac by just moving the folder to the trash and installed a fresh copy. Usually, during installation, it asks for admin password but this time it did not.

From terminal, when I type `ipython`, I get the following error:

> zsh: command not found: ipython

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You more than likely need to add the new Anaconda installation to your system path.

https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/macos.html

Note the export PATH="$HOME/miniconda/bin:$PATH" line. This needs to point to your new installation location.

Also worth noting the Changelog since Anaconda 4.4 was released - https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

There are decisions to be made about how you wish to 'start' your conda (which environment / which users have ability etc) that you need to make choices for.

Very good answer here for similar issue - [Conda command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35246386/conda-command-not-found)