# After installing spyder, conda module is not found

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, miniconda

After I installed spyder IDE through running `$ conda install spyder`

Whenever I try to run any `conda` command I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/homero/miniconda3/bin/conda", line 12, in <module>
    from conda.cli import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda'
```

How can I fix this?

Edit:

- When I start python I get the following:

$ python

Python 3.7.2 (default, Dec 29 2018, 06:19:36) 
    [GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

- I have `export PATH="/home/homero/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"` on my .bashrc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching a lot, found this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/46503868/1273751) that solved my problem:

```
$ curl https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -o ~/miniconda3.sh
$ bash ~/miniconda3.sh -bfp ~/miniconda3
```