# ModuleNotFoundError when importing TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, anaconda

I tried to import TensorFlow(downloaded it through pip) to Jupyter notebook or PyCharm ce but I get ModuleNotFound Error on both. Also I installed Anaconda before and deleted the app, but I think the files remained and when I try to write 'conda' in terminal, it says command not found.

Comment: installed using `pip or pip3`?

Comment: Oh I used pip3.

Comment: added the environment variable?

Comment: What is that? Could you explain

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35246386/conda-command-not-found

Answer (score 0):

These steps will help you to install Tensorflow in Anaconda

```
1. Download the anaconda package from https://www.anaconda.com/download/

or 

curl -O https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-x-x-x-x.sh

2. Verify the Data Integrity of the Installer  (optional)
sha256sum Anaconda3-x-x-x-x.sh

3. Run the Anaconda Script
bash Anaconda3-x-x-x-x.sh

4. Activate Installation
source ~/.bashrc

5. Test Installation
conda list

6. Set Up Anaconda Environments
conda create --name tf python=3

7. Activate the new Environment
source activate tf

8. Install Tensorflow
tf$pip install tensorflow
```