# conda: command not found | Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, ubuntu-18.04

Current Issue: I installed Python 3.9 but Python 3.8 is still being used. How do I delete Python 3.8?

---

I want to download [SimLoRD](https://bitbucket.org/genomeinformatics/simlord/src/master/) on `Ubuntu 18.04`, as a fresh platform for exclusively this task. First thing is to download `Anaconda`, which is installed, and then [Bioconda](https://anaconda.org/bioconda/simlord).

In Linux `Terminal`, bash:

```
conda install -c bioconda simlord
conda: command not found
```

I had tried creating a separate environment:

```
conda create --name myenvironment simlord
conda: command not found
```

---

I've had this `Unsatisfiable Error` response now:

[image: Linux Terminal]

[image: Windows Terminal]

Reading the `Linux Terminal` message, I **think** it wants me to be either on Python 2.7 or Python 3.9. I am on Python 3.8.

---

I followed this [tutorial](https://tech.serhatteker.com/post/2020-09/how-to-install-python39-on-ubuntu/) and installed `Python 3.9`:

[image: Linux Terminal using Python 3.8 but saying I have Python 3.9]

I've been stuck on this for a few days. Feel like I've tried everything :(

Comment: I think you're trying to install conda from within python. The `>>>` looks like the python terminal to me. You should do the install from the Ubuntu Terminal

Comment: Sorry, I stupidly added >>> Let me remove. I am installing via Linux Terminal/ Bash

Comment: Oh, ok. makes sense now lol.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conda command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35246386/conda-command-not-found)

Comment: @revmatcher Sorry, I've not done that setup. I don't recognise that code.

Comment: Your terminal prompt should have a `(base)` on the far left. That tells you that you have `conda` activated. When you set-up `conda`, I think it should have added it to your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`. At least that is what happens with MacOS and I vaguely recall that happens on Ubuntu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run Conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675907/how-to-run-conda)