# Use conda in linux

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I install anaconda in my ubuntu , but I don't use Conda.
I have this error and I don't fix this.

```
mamal@DESKTOP-H4B5SN5:~$ conda create -n pars
conda: command not found
mamal@DESKTOP-H4B5SN5:~$ /boot/anaconda3/bin/conda create -n pars
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

UnavailableInvalidChannel: The channel is not accessible or is invalid.
  channel name: pkgs/main
  channel url: https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main
  error code: 403

You will need to adjust your conda configuration to proceed.
Use `conda config --show channels` to view your configuration's current state,
and use `conda config --show-sources` to view config file locations.
```

Comment: is it really supposed to get installed to `/boot`? i haven't used conda on linux, but that seems odd

Comment: You have probably not the permissions to create the environment in this folder.

Comment: Thank's bro, but no. I have this error in default directory that anaconda use for install their packages .like this

Comment: `conda: command not found` see https://stackoverflow.com/q/35246386/11301900.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed this by configuration .condarc file and add some channel. Like forge