# How to run bash EXPORT command in dockerfile and have it stick?

Tags: python, bash, docker, conda

I am trying to do [as the linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35246386/conda-command-not-found), but inside a dockerfile.

I have conda installed in the docker in the path `/miniconda/bin`. Entering bash in the docker and doing `conda` gives `bash: conda: command not found`. In that bash, manually doing `export PATH="/miniconda/bin:$PATH"` makes it know `conda`.

I want that in the dockerfile.

Whatever I try, `/miniconda/bin` is not added to the `PATH`.

---

Things I tried:

`RUN export PATH="/miniconda/bin:$PATH"` - PATH is not affected.

in the entrypoint script: `export PATH="/miniconda/bin":$PATH` - PATH is not affected.

How to make the PATH know conda?

Comment: Have you looked at how official Docker images are built? See [Miniconda Dockerfiles](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/docker-images/tree/master/miniconda3) or [Miniforge Dockerfile](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge-images/blob/master/ubuntu/Dockerfile).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every `RUN` statement  is it's own shell execution, so when the RUN command is done, any environment variables you set are lost. That's why `RUN export` doesn't work.

You can use the ENV statement to make it stick, like this

```
ENV PATH=/miniconda/bin:$PATH
```

Edit: My test of setting it. Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:bullseye
ENV PATH=/my/path:$PATH
```

Build and run

```
docker build -t test .
docker run --rm test bash -c "echo $PATH"
```

Output:

```
/my/path:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Comment: Why didn't it work from the startup script?

Comment: Just tried it, still doesn't seem to stick. Don't know why

Comment: @Gulzar I've added the Dockerfile I used to test to my answer

Comment: This is the answer to the question, that turned out to be the wrong question. My problem was the env variables don't stick when connecting with ssh.

Comment: @Gulzar That happens. Glad you solved it.