# Docker build issue with conda (miniconda)

Tags: python, docker, artificial-intelligence, conda, minecraft

First, a bit of context : I'm curently trying to work on [**MineRL**](https://minerl.io/), and to put this in a **docker**. I'm using **WSL 2** on my **Windows** machine to make docker work correctly. There is the github where i found the **dockerfile** I used : [GitHub](https://github.com/manuelsh/minerl-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile).

When running the dockerfile with

```bash
docker build - < Dockerfile
```

Everything works perfectly until i reach step **[9/18]**, Which is about **conda**.
Here is the error i had :

```
=> ERROR [ 9/18] RUN /home/user/miniconda/bin/conda install conda-build  && /home/user/miniconda/bin/conda create -y --name py37 python=3.7.3    0.8s 
------
 > [ 9/18] RUN /home/user/miniconda/bin/conda install conda-build  && /home/user/miniconda/bin/conda create -y --name py37 python=3.7.3  && /home/user/miniconda/bin/conda clean -ya:
#12 0.739 /bin/sh: 1: /home/user/miniconda/bin/conda: not found
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c /home/user/miniconda/bin/conda install conda-build  && /home/user/miniconda/bin/conda create -y --name py37 python=3.7.3  && /home/user/miniconda/bin/conda clean -ya]: exit code: 127
```

I found a solution on this [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35246386/conda-command-not-found) but it couldn't resolve my problems.

Then i am asking anyone who is used to docker, conda and maybe MineRL some help on this please!

EDIT : Thanks to @lote and @DobbyTheElf, I mannaged to **modify some part of the dockerfil**e to correspond to **my configuration**, but it still cannot find the conda file. Here is my new [Dockerfile](https://github.com/AlexandreFrancony/MineRL/blob/master/Dockerfile).

To be sure about what @DobbyTheElf told me, I ran this command to find the path to the folder "**miniconda3**" and the result is underneath the request :

```
bloster@DESKTOP-UATBDIM:~/miniconda3/bin$ find / -name miniconda3
/home/bloster/miniconda3
```

So i edited again my code to what it is now (by the time my last git commit is called "[first push](https://github.com/AlexandreFrancony/MineRL/commit/839e35c8e6f8b94072968aea117f2b0d92a44d18)").
**The error remains the same for now...**

Comment: maybe it should be miniconda3 instead of miniconda in the runing path

Comment: What does `ls /home/user/miniconda/bin/` return?

Comment: @lote i tried, and i think it's a good track to follow, but the error remains the same even after i changed the path everywhere it was required

Comment: @DobbyTheElf, I tried it even after the previous answer, and tried to adapt it to "miniconda3", i think i'm alreadu in /home/user, so i did
`ls /miniconda3/bin/` and i had the files which are inside "bin" where i could find the conda file.

Comment: Note that whether or not your current directory is /home/user, if you are saying that `ls /miniconda3/bin/` produced a good result, then it means that miniconda3 is installed in the root directory, and not under /home/user, and thus you should remove the /home/user references from your scripts.

Comment: @DobbyTheElf Thanks for the help, it didn't solve the problem tho... but you had a good point, i think it helps as much as using miniconda3 instead of miniconda