# Why can I not install miniconda to another directory rather than `HOME`?

Tags: linux, docker, miniconda

[Here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/miniconda/en/latest/) are the official instructions to installing miniconda on Linux -

```
mkdir -p ~/miniconda3
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/miniconda3/miniconda.sh
bash ~/miniconda3/miniconda.sh -b -u -p ~/miniconda3
rm -rf ~/miniconda3/miniconda.sh
```

However, I'd like to install it in a different location than `HOME` `(cd~)` in my Docker container.

Therefore, this is what I did -

```
RUN cd / \
    && mkdir -p /my_folder/miniconda3 \
    && wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O /my_folder/miniconda3/miniconda.sh \
    && bash /my_folder/miniconda3/miniconda.sh -b -u -p /my_folder/miniconda3 \
    && rm -rf /my_folder/miniconda3/miniconda.sh \
    && /my_folder/miniconda3/bin/conda init bash \
    && conda init \
    && conda create -y -n myenv python=3.8
```

However, that leads me to an error -

```
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c cd /     && mkdir -p my_folder/miniconda3     && wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O /my_folder/miniconda3/miniconda.sh     && bash miniconda3/miniconda.sh -b -u -p /my_folder/miniconda3     && rm -rf /my_folder/miniconda3/miniconda.sh     && /my_folder/miniconda3/bin/conda init bash     && conda init     && conda create -y -n myenv python=3.8" did not complete successfully: exit code: 127
```

Here is my entire Docker file for reference -

```
FROM nvcr.io/nvidia/cuda:12.2.2-devel-ubuntu22.04



WORKDIR /app


RUN echo "Hello World!"
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libosmesa6-dev \
    sudo \
    wget \
    curl \
    unzip \
    gcc \
    g++ \
    &&  apt-get install \
    libosmesa6-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive



RUN cd / \
    && mkdir -p /my_folder/miniconda3 \
    && wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O /my_folder/miniconda3/miniconda.sh \
    && bash /my_folder/miniconda3/miniconda.sh -b -u -p /my_folder/miniconda3 \
    && rm -rf /my_folder/miniconda3/miniconda.sh \
    && /my_folder/miniconda3/bin/conda init bash \
    && conda init \
    && conda create -y -n myenv python=3.8
```

Update 1:

One of the commentators pointed out that I made a silly error on this line - `bash miniconda3/miniconda.sh -b -u -p /my_folder/miniconda3 \`. It should be `bash /my_folder/miniconda3/miniconda.sh -b -u -p /my_folder/miniconda3 \`. I have fixed the above code too. However, the error still persists.

For debugging purposes, I split my RUN commands and found that the line causing this error seems to be this - `&& conda init \`

Comment: You download to `/my_folder/miniconda3/miniconda.sh` and then try to run `bash miniconda3/miniconda.sh`. You must change that to `bash my_folder/miniconda3/miniconda.sh`.

Comment: Thank you. I fixed that mistake. However, the error still persists.

Comment: For the sake of debugging, you could try separating that all-in-one `RUN` into separate steps, then you'll know for sure.

Comment: Yep, already done that,

Comment: Ah, I see the problem. I had to do `ENV PATH="/my_folder/miniconda3/bin:${PATH}"
ARG PATH="/my_folder/miniconda3/bin:${PATH}"`. The official instructions didn't have that.
@JoachimSauer Should I delete this question. It might be helpful to someone else who got lost after following official instructions.

Comment: Feel free to post a self-answer with the solution, this way it might be more useful. The comments should not be the only long-term "storage" of such knowledge.

Comment: Ah, I just found a similar SO post that describes the need for PATH variable (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35246386/conda-command-not-found). To prevent duplication, I will just delete it. Let me know if you'd like me to do something else.