# Anaconda: disable prompt change

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, anaconda

When using anaconda (install for python), when I switch to the virtual env with this:

```
source activate my_env
```

It changes my prompt and adds (my_env) at the start of my PS1.

I've tried adding `export VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1` to my bashrc, but it did not help.

Any idea?

Comment: This is deeply worrying. If anaconda thinks it has the right to edit `.bash_profile` in a way which changes the prompt, what else does it (mistakenly) think it has the right to do? Turns out, it also adds to the beginning of `PATH` so that, for example, `curl` is redefined. Ouch! I’m treating this as malware.

Comment: @AdamChalcraft This seems to be an overreaction. Anaconda is a well-established and widely used tool, and this is a normally very useful feature. If the user loses track of which environment they're in, they'll likely get strange errors and broken dependencies. I also don't think it's a surprise that a tool whose purpose is to create isolated and self-consistent virtual environments within your system will redefine some of your important exeutables - how else would it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are like me, you **like** the **non-default environment** to show up if you have activated it, but **don't want to clutter up your prompt** in other cases -
(e.g. you happen to use bash for reasons having nothing to do with python)

Place the following excerpt in your ~/.bash_profile right after the section managed by conda:

```
# ahj - remove the default Python environment artifact "(base)" from prompt
PS1=$(echo "$PS1" | perl -pe 's/^\(base\)\s*//' )
```

Comment: While this solution may work, it treats the symptoms rather than the cause. I'm wondering why it was marked the accepted answer.

Comment: I love how it only filters out base. What if I switch branches?

Answer (score 102):

Run this on the terminal:

```
$ conda config --set changeps1 False
```

http://conda.pydata.org/docs/config.html#change-command-prompt-changeps1

Comment: Any idea on how to do that just for the base environment? (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54725966/1273751)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55171696/how-to-remove-base-from-terminal-prompt-after-updating-conda

Comment: Is there any way to make this same change but for PS2 env variable? `conda config --set changeps2 False` did not work :(

Comment: Just in case you stumbled upon this because of an issue with **posh-git**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70527216/5561649

Comment: This didn't work for me. But used answer from saza, which worked: conda config --set auto_activate_base False

Answer (score 28):

Add:

```
changeps1: False
```

to your .condarc file.

http://conda.pydata.org/docs/config.html#change-command-prompt-changeps1

Answer (score 17):

I've had a slightly different, but related problem: how to avoid the base env to be activated by default for every terminal window. Solution:

`conda config --set auto_activate_base False`

*Note: this only works if you have run conda init first.*

Comment: ONce you have done this, how do you get back a terminal with (base) ?

Comment: Hey @Bram, that's simple, just run `conda activate`, it will activate the base environment! Cheers

Comment: Correct answer - I use terminal a lot and often for things not related to python so I can't have conda intrude everywhere. But when I use it, I want to see it. This solution does that.