# Identify SHELL Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, conda, iterm2

I tried to `activate` a `conda` environment that I created but I got an error saying `your shell isn't initialised` and I ran `conda init zsh` then `conda init bash` and then `conda init zsh`.

I then restarted my terminal (iTerm). While I am able to run the env I created, I am seeing this annoying `(base)` at above user name.

How do I get back original display without this `(base)`[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove (base) from terminal prompt after updating conda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55171696/how-to-remove-base-from-terminal-prompt-after-updating-conda)

Comment: Thanks @merv the accepted solution worked.