# Anaconda(conda), how to show only a non-base environment

Tags: bash, terminal, anaconda, conda, command-prompt

I use macos + anaconda (conda 4.8.2). 
How to show only a non-base environment on the console.

I want to get the next behavior:

in case of "base" environment command prompt should look like:

```
~/dir1/dir2$
```

in case of the non-base environment:

```
(non-base)~/dir1/dir2$
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove (base) from terminal prompt after updating conda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55171696/how-to-remove-base-from-terminal-prompt-after-updating-conda)

Comment: @merv Yep. I know this solution but I'm looking for something more direct and safe.