# How to stop python from installing modules in specific virtual environment and install them globally?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I was wondering How can I stop python from installing modules in specific virtual environment and install them globally;or probably virtaulenv won't let me do that!?

Comment: use `deactivate` command

Answer (score 1):

if you have `(venv)` before you terminal input, your virtual environment is activates. so you can using `deactivate` command for deactivating. in addition if you have a `(base)` you should be closing your anaconda base environment so you can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55172508/14285494)

Answer (score 1):

You simply install the package without activating your virtual environment. Once you install your package that way, it would be installed globally instead of inside a global environment.

Also, to confirm this, you can activate your virtual environment and run the command `pip list` , this will show all the packages in that virtual environment, and also try deactivating the virtual environment and run the command `pip list`, this would show all packages in the system.

I hope this answers your question

Comment: it installs all packages without active venv  in specific virtual environment

Comment: isn't that what you wanted, if not maybe you should be more concise as regards what you want. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've found some sort of solution ,by just typing "pip install -target C:\Users\YOURNAME\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages"
it's kind of a lame solution but I think it's better than nothing!
By the way there was no pip.exe in my python folder!!!