# How to remove base from terminal after installing anaconda

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, conda

**A common question for anaconda new user - after installing anaconda in Linux it's displaying 'base' in the terminal by default**

```
(base)user007:~$ anaconda-navigator
```

Now I want to remove (base) permanently from the terminal without deactivating conda.

I tried the following source but didn't help me altogether.
Either it was deactivating conda after removing (base) or activated conda but didn't remove (base) permanently from terminal.

[stackoverflow.com/questions/54429210/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54429210/how-do-i-prevent-conda-from-activating-the-base-environment-by-default)

[askubuntu.com/questions/1026383](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026383/why-does-base-appear-in-front-of-my-terminal-prompt)

Comment: Per the current answer, duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55171696/how-to-remove-base-from-terminal-prompt-after-updating-conda.

Comment: Yeah, I've given the reference link already and added the 4th point.  Without it, didn't work for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After researching all solution I reached an end from this link
[stackoverflow.com/questions/55171696](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55171696/how-to-remove-base-from-terminal-prompt-after-updating-conda)

1. check By default, auto_activate_base is set to True or False when installing anaconda

   ```
    $ conda config --show | grep auto_activate_base
   ```
2. If it appears `auto_activate_base: False` after running the above command.
   Then run

   ```
    $conda config --set auto_activate_base True
   ```
3. Then run `$conda config --set changeps1 False` it will hide (env) completely, and in case you want to show (env) only when it's activated, you can set changeps1 to True.
4. Finally add `source ~/anaconda3/bin/activate root` to bashrc file and save it.

#Now it won't show (base) anymore & conda will open smoothly.

To check it run `$anaconda-navigator`