# Conda environment name hides git branch after conda init in Powershell

Tags: git, powershell, conda

I have the Posh-Git module installed for Powershell and, recently, I also installed Anaconda and did `conda init`. Apparently, this modifies the `profile.ps1` file by adding the following code:

```
#region conda initialize
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
(& "{User}\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe" "shell.powershell" "hook") | Out-String | Invoke-Expression
#endregion
```

This does let me see the conda environment I'm working with but it also hides the Git branch I'm working on. How do I modify this so that I can see both?

Comment: Maybe try playing with Conda's `env_prompt` configuration variable. Check the documentation with `conda config --describe env_prompt`.

Comment: @merv That just changes conda displays for the conda-specific prefix. It doesn't stop blocking my git branch

Comment: Yeah, I thought maybe something specific about what Conda inserts could be the problem

Comment: @merv It appears not. My guess is that the script they use in `conda init` is intercepting the output from posh-git but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The posh-git [docs](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git#customizing-the-posh-git-prompt) state that posh-git won't modify a custom prompt. So when you run `Import-Module posh-git` after conda has initialized, you won't see anything change. The solution is to put `Import-Module posh-git` before the conda initialization block in your `$Profile.CurrentUserAllHosts` file so it looks like:

```
Import-Module posh-git

#region conda initialize
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
(& "{User}\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe" "shell.powershell" "hook") | Out-String | Invoke-Expression
#endregion
```

It's worth also noting that when you run `Add-PoshGitToProfile`, it adds the `Import-Module posh-git` line to your `$Profile.CurrentUserCurrentHost` file. Since this executes *after* `$Profile.CurrentUserAllHosts`, that command will not have any noticeable effect.