# Anaconda does not work on python3?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, conda

I downloaded anaconda packaged installer(for python3.5 and 64bit) for osx El Capitan.

After I successfully installed anaconda, I can use matplotlib and other modules on python2. However, I cannot use these modules in python3.

So, I googled and found similar one ([How to run Conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675907/how-to-run-conda))
I checked my `.bash_profile` and found that it automatically created code for anaconda

```
# added by Anaconda3 4.0.0 installer
 export PATH="/Users/username/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

this is my `.bash_profile` code for python3

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"
```

However, I still cannot import module on python 3, and cannot use command `conda` on command shell.

What should I need to run conda and import modules on python3??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You did not properly delete Python. python3 is referencing a python version downloaded from python.org not the one downloaded with anaconda.

Check this link on how to properly delete old version https://nektony.com/how-to/uninstall-python-on-mac

Answer (score 0):

I found simple solution(?). Close all opened terminal windows, and reopen then try `conda` or import modules. It works!