# After installing anaconda - command not found: jupyter

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I have installed anaconda on my MAC laptop, and tried to run jupyter notebook to install it, but I get error jupyter command not found.

Comment: to be clear: `jupyter notebook` opens a notebook in the browser; it does not install jupyter. that should just come as part of anaconda installation.

Comment: Have you tried to restart the terminal so the new paths take effect?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You need to activate your conda environment (`source bin/activate`) and then do

```
$ pip install jupyter # Alternatively, you can do `conda install jupyter`
$ jupyter notebook # to actually run the notebook server
```

Comment: Is your conda environment activated? i.e did you do `source bin/activate` ?

Comment: source bin/activate - that was it! wasn't aware that I need to do that as well! thanks!

Comment: [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675907/how-to-run-conda) talks about how to activate `conda`. TL;DR use `export PATH=~/anaconda2/bin:$PATH` after installing Anaconda

Comment: @AdamMThompson If you do `source bin/activate` your path should be modified for you by that script.

Comment: You need to run that command from the anaconda folder (if you've downloaded and installed the package)

Comment: I am new to the macOS, anyone pls tell me how can I activate the anaconda. In the command prompt when I write conda --version  it says command not found. how can i do that `source bin/activate`

Comment: @AadnanFarooqA you need to install conda first. There are instructions on the official website on how to do so. If you get stuck there, please ask a new question with your problem. Link to install instructions - https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/macos.html

Comment: If using conda, you should `conda install jupyter`, not pip

Comment: Can you be more explicit? what is source bin/activate?

Comment: Thank you so much for this!!!! I was going nuts trying to figure out why I can't get jupyter to open

Answer (score 21):

Add `$HOME/anaconda3/bin` to your `$PATH` and `jupyter-notebook` should work. There are a ton of other binaries you can lookup in that folder as well.

```
export PATH=$HOME/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

then

```
jupyter-notebook
```

Comment: It may be installed into the opt folder now. I configured .zshrc with `export PATH=$HOME/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH` and can confirm jupyter-notebook now works.

Answer (score 10):

@ffledgling anwser did not work for me. What did solve was to install jupyter using conda:

`conda install jupyter`

That did the trick. Right after the installation finished I went with

`jupyter notebook`

as my next command and saw the server setup and the browser page opening.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem on my Mac OS. I'm also new to Python, so forgive me if this is an obvious solution. 
What solved it for me was installing Python with the 'install for me only' option rather than the hard-drive option.  If it tells you you can't, then reselect it.  After that, the command jupyter notebook opened without a problem.
Hope it can help someone!

[How to](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install#next)

[image: Installation Screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

It could be as simple as opening a new Terminal window.

Answer (score 2):

## For Windows

After you can successfully run `conda` from powershell, you can install jupyter with: 
 `conda install jupyter` 
 command. Then re-open powershell and run 
 `conda run jupyter notebook`.

Comment: Thanks, All we need is to run cmdlets with conda prefix, in my case  zsh:"jupyter notebook"  "error:upyter notebook  cmd could not found".  Actual cmd: "conda run jupyter notebook"

Answer (score 1):

If your issue is happening after running `conda install jupyter`, you can use `conda init zsh` to configure the `~/.zshrc` automatically so that when you just type `jupyter notebook` on terminal, it can find it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem try this instead

```
jupyter-notebook
```

Comment: you saved me, this works!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Mac. I am using Miniconda
Opened ~/.zshrc profile on nano as, *nano ~/.zshrc*
and added the location of miniconda on my mac as the last line of the ~/.zshrc as:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/bin:$PATH"
```

solves the issue easily.

Comment: The issue arises as you haven't configured the environment variables

Comment: It depends on which shell you are using. I am using Zsh

Comment: Was everything working otherwise? I believe that manually adding conda to the PATH is discouraged in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Open a new terminal and try again, it worked for me. This is written somewhere in the installation guide "For this change to become active, you have to open a new terminal."

Answer (score 0):

### If it's a fresh installation. Close the the terminal and re-open

- You don't have to install jupyter explicitly. Anaconda does for you.
- **Ensure the environment is activated first.**
- If you selected Yes when prompted "Do you wish the installer to initialize Anaconda3 by running conda init? [yes|no]" during installation, prepend your commands with conda
- mycomp@55:~$ conda activate
- (base) mycomp@55:~$ jupyter notebook

Answer (score 0):

After installing Anaconda on windows 10, you can use Anaconda prompt from start menu to activate a conda enabled terminal window.
You can run Jupyter from that window using:

```
jupyter notebook
```

Answer (score -1):

You should first have conda in your PATH environment. You can achieve it taking a look on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675907/how-to-run-conda).

Now you just need to run `jupyter notebook`.