# Python pip install h5py met TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'Retry' and 'int'

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

I want to install h5py module on ubuntu 16.04 LTS with Python 2.7.12, but I met following problem.Below is the traceback.And I'm in mainland of China, there is great firewall, is there anything to do with it? Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks. 
I used the command line:

```
pip install h5py
Collecting h5py
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 328, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 748, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 360, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 512, in _prepare_file
    finder, self.upgrade, require_hashes)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 273, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 442, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 400, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 545, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 648, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 757, in get_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 480, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 378, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 46, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/adapters.py", line 376, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 610, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 228, in increment
    total -= 1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'Retry' and 'int'
```

When I add sudo in the command line, the error prompt is different.

```
sudo pip inatall h5py
The directory '/home/yangyong/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/yangyong/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting h5py
  Downloading h5py-2.6.0-1-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (4.2MB)
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 360, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 577, in _prepare_file
    session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 810, in unpack_url
    hashes=hashes
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 649, in unpack_http_url
    hashes)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 871, in _download_http_url
    _download_url(resp, link, content_file, hashes)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 595, in _download_url
    hashes.check_against_chunks(downloaded_chunks)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/hashes.py", line 46, in check_against_chunks
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 563, in written_chunks
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/ui.py", line 139, in iter
    for x in it:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 552, in resp_read
    decode_content=False):
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/response.py", line 344, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/response.py", line 311, in read
    flush_decoder = True
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 35, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/response.py", line 240, in _error_catcher
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, 'Read timed out.')
ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Read timed out.
```

Comment: Thanks.@DavidZemens. I solved the problem by installing anaconda. And I set the path,then it works.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have solved my problem. I installed anaconda on ubuntu 16.04, but I didn't set the path. Now I added [PATH=$PATH:$HOME/anaconda2/bin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675907/how-to-run-conda) to .bashrc. Then anaconda works fine. Because anaconda already includes h5py module.