# IPython ImportError: cannot import name Layout

Tags: python, plot, ipython, catboost

I'm trying CatBoost based on [this article](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/08/catboost-automated-categorical-data/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Feed%3A%20AnalyticsVidhya%20%28Analytics%20Vidhya%29)

In it's code, CatBoost has `plot` in `model.fit()`, so I want to try it on my IPython.

Here's my CatBoost code:

```
from catboost import CatBoostRegressor

# indicate categorical features for CatBoost
categorical_features_indices = np.where(X.dtypes != np.float)[0]

model=CatBoostRegressor(iterations=50, depth=3, learning_rate=0.1, 
loss_function='RMSE')
model.fit(X_train, y_train, 
cat_features=categorical_features_indices,
          use_best_model=True,
          eval_set=(X_validation, y_validation), plot=True)
```

But, it cannot show any plot and kept giving me error:

[image]

I did install ipywidgets and ipython.
Do you know how to deal with this problem?

Comment: Are you running ipython as a notebook or shell? Are you running it in a virtual environment?

Comment: I run it as notebook. I tried both virtual environment and non-virtual environment, both got this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I solved the problem, and now I can see this plot

[image]

In my case, the solution is to install `Conda` and create a conda virtual environment, then install `ipywidgets` through Conda.
Let me write down all the details here, hope it will help. **This may only help Mac users**

1. Download Conda here: https://www.continuum.io/downloads
2. Add conda into `$PATH`: [How to run Conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675907/how-to-run-conda)
3. Create Conda virtual environment `conda create -n yourenvname python=x.x anaconda`
4. Activate conda virtual environment `source activate yourenvname`
5. Install IPython Notebook in this virtual environment (if you have already user python `virtualenv` and installed IPython for that, you can skip this step):

   - `(yourenvname)$ pip install jupyter`
   - `(yourenvname)$ pip install ipykernel`
   - `(yourenvname)$ python -m ipykernel install --user --name testenv --display-name "Python2 (yourenvname)"`, if you have multiple ipykernel, here `testenv` should also be changed to another name
6. Install ipywidgets, `(yourenvname)$ conda install ipywidgets --no-deps`
7. Install catboost, `(yourenvname)$ pip install catboost`
8. Turn on Jupyter Notebook, `jupyter notebook` and create a new notebook under `Python2 (yourenvname)`, then it should work

NOTE: **If doesn't work, before step 8**, try this:

- `pip install widgetsnbextension`
- `jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension --sys-prefix`