# Conda environment

Tags: django, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

I created a conda environment, which I called MyDjangoEnv. When I try to activate it using `source activate MyDjangoEnv` I get the error:

> No such file or directory.

I tried installing a different version of Python with `conda create --name MyDjangoEnv python=3`, but I get the error:

> conda: the order was not found

Comment: This thread might have solution to this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675907/how-to-run-conda

Answer (score 2):

You might need to set the path using

**for anaconda 2 :**

```
export PATH=~/anaconda2/bin:$PATH
```

**for anaconda 3 :**

```
export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

**for anaconda 4 :**

Use the Anaconda Prompt

and then

```
conda --version
```

to confirm that it worked.