# How to delete Anaconda from Mac

Tags: python, anaconda

I try to delete anaconda from mac but when I type in

```
conda install anaconda-clean
anaconda-clean --yes
```

I get -bash: conda: command not found. What I have to do?

Comment: Do you have conda added in the PATH?

Comment: I don't know. Where can I check this?

Comment: `echo $PATH`. If you can't find anaconda, you should try this first https://stackoverflow.com/a/35717840/7570485

Comment: /Users/daniel/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/php5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Comment: which anaconda version are you using?

Comment: Anaconda3-5.2.0-MacOSX-x86_64