# Unable to run conda outside of bash?

Tags: python, bash, macos, terminal, conda

> -bash: conda: command not found

I tried following this 
[How to run Conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675907/how-to-run-conda)

but every time I have to type

```
export PATH=~/miniconda3/bin:$PATH
```

I tried adding to `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` but then what happened is :

When I open terminal conda command won't work but when I type bash and enter bash and then I type conda it works perfectly fine .

Any suggestions how to make conda work outside of bash ?

P.S I am using MAC

My .bash_profile

```
export ANDROID_SDK = "/Users/vivanksharma/Downloads/Tools
export PATH = $PATH:"$ANDROID_SDK/tools:$ANDROID_SDK/platform-tools"

# added by Anaconda3 5.2.0 installer
export PATH="/Volumes/MACExtended/Softwares/Python/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"

# Setting PATH for Python 3.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"


# added by Miniconda3 installer
export PATH="~/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: Open your terminal and run this command: `echo $0`. What is the output?

Comment: Output is `-bash` @haccks

Comment: You just have toadd `export PATH=~/miniconda3/bin:$PATH` the `.bash_profile` to add the path and then run `source ~/.bash_profile`. Try it and let me know.

Comment: `.bash_profile: line 13: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
` and `.bash_profile: line 14: syntax error: unexpected end of file
` getting error @haccks

Comment: I have updated my question with .bash_profile file can you help me out @haccks

Comment: The first line is missing closing `"`. You need to fix that.

Comment: thanks @haccks for your kind help

Comment: Does it worked? Let me know. It may help other users having same issue.

Comment: yep it worked @haccks