# Conda command not found in Google Cloud VM

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, anaconda, conda

I have a problem with Anaconda3 in Google Cloud VM with Ubuntu. I installed Anaconda3 successfully, but I cannot call conda. Here is code from my terminal.

```
eko_rudiawan@google-ubuntu:~$ $PATH
-bash: /home/eko_rudiawan/bin:/home/eko_rudiawan/.local/bin:/opt/ros/kinetic/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/us
r/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin: No such file or directory
eko_rudiawan@google-ubuntu:~$ which python
/usr/bin/python
eko_rudiawan@google-ubuntu:~$ export PATH="/home/eko_rudiawan/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
eko_rudiawan@google-ubuntu:~$ which python
/home/eko_rudiawan/anaconda3/bin/python
eko_rudiawan@google-ubuntu:~$ conda --version
conda: command not found
eko_rudiawan@google-ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: Possible duplicate [How to run Conda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55526573/570918). Note the newer recommendation is to use `conda init` instead of editing `PATH`.  Also, is `conda` not an executable in your `anaconda3/bin/` folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is to start from the begging. I had the same issue in my VM and I fixed with these steps:

1. SSH to you VM from the Google Cloud Console
2. Run `$ ls` command to see if the **anaconda3** directory is there
3. If it is execute `$ rm -rf anaconda3`. This will force to delete the directory and all its data.
4. After that execute `$ exit` to exit the VM or close the window to terminate session.
5. SSH to the VM again
6. Now we will install the anaconda3. I will post the commands below but you can refer to this documentation: [How To Install Anaconda on Ubuntu 18.04 [Quickstart]](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-anaconda-on-ubuntu-18-04-quickstart).
7. Download the Anaconda Bash Script. Execute:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ curl -O https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-5.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

8. Verify the Data Integrity of the Installer

```
$ sha256sum Anaconda3-5.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh

Output
09f53738b0cd3bb96f5b1bac488e5528df9906be2480fe61df40e0e0d19e3d48  Anaconda3-5.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

9. Run the Anaconda Script

```
$ bash Anaconda3-5.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

10. Pres `ENTER`. Keep pressing enter until the first question comes up.
11. When asked **Do you accept the license terms? [yes|no]**, type `yes` hit **ENTER**.
12. When asked:

```
Anaconda3 will now be installed into this location:
/home/[YOUR_USERNAME]/anaconda3

  - Press ENTER to confirm the location
  - Press CTRL-C to abort the installation
  - Or specify a different location below

[/home/[YOUR_USERNAME]/anaconda3] >>>
```

13. Hit **ENTER**. This will take some time and a lot of files will be installed.
14. When asked **Do you wish the installer to prepend the Anaconda3 install location
    to PATH in your /home/cusnir/.bashrc ? [yes|no]**, type `yes` hit **ENTER**.
15. Now you should see: `Thank you for installing Anaconda3!`
16. When asked **Do you wish to proceed with the installation of Microsoft VSCode? [yes|no]** type `no` and hit **ENTER**.
17. Go to main directory by executing `$ cd`
18. If you execute `$ ls`. You should see the `anaconda3` directory there.
19. You can activate the anaconda environment by executing: `$ source anaconda3/bin/activate`
20. Now you should see `(base) [YOUR_USERNAME]@ubuntu-linux-os:~$`. Which **(base)** means you are inside that environment.
21. Execute: `$ conda --version`
22. You should get `conda 4.5.4` response.
23. However you can also do that without the **step 18**. Just when you SSH to the VM execute `conda --version` and you should see the anaconda's version.

Comment: Done, I miss this part source anaconda3/bin/activate

Comment: I am glad that I could help

Answer (score 1):

Old question but I just encountered the same issue. I only needed to do step 19 to get conda to work. No need to start over. However the fix didn't stick - had to repeat on next terminal session.