# conda not found after Anaconda installation on windows 10

Tags: anaconda, conda

I installed anaconda in

```
C:\Users\place_holder\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3
```

I added the followings to the PATH env variable:

```
  C:\Users\place_holder\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3
  C:\Users\place_holder\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts
```

Then I tried conda:

```
  C:\Users\place_holder>conda
    'conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Then I tried to find it

```
dir C:\Users\place_holder\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\conda*
 Volume in drive C is OSDisk
 Volume Serial Number is 40C4-D1E4
 Directory of C:\Users\place_holder\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts

04/15/2019  09:34 AM               465 conda-verify-script.py
10/03/2018  08:38 AM            74,752 conda-verify.exe
               2 File(s)         75,217 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  712,939,847,680 bytes free
```

What seems to be wrong?

Comment: open anaconda prompt and type conda

Comment: @MariosNikolaou Even at Anaconda Prompt, 'conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: This sounds like a duplicate of [How to run conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675907/how-to-run-conda?answertab=active#tab-top). Can you verify what version of Conda you're running? e.g., add output from  `C:\Users\place_holder\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\bin\conda info` to your question.

Comment: @merv To rephrase the problem: There is no conda executable file in the entire. anaconda3. Are you sure that a "bin" folder is found under anaconda3 ( as mentioned in the path provided by you? I  don't see any bin folder in anaconda3.Note that the question is specific to Windows. There might be bin folder on Unix etc..

Comment: @qqqqq something went wrong with the installation, it's better to uninstall and re install, if you download from official anaconda site and install it will be ok.I have done it many times.