# conda activate is not working : no any reaction

Tags: python, macos, terminal, conda

I am trying to install zipline for algorithm trading, so i have to create a conda's venv for python 3.5 version. However, after create the env, when i activating this env, there is no PARENTHESIS. If it works, the command line should be like this with (env_name) right?

```
Youngs-MacBookPro:~ young$ conda env list
WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
# conda environments:
#
base                     /Users/young/anaconda3
env_zipline           *  /Users/young/anaconda3/envs/env_zipline
```

The creation is worked like above and after activating i cannot see any PARENTHESIS like (env_name).

```
Youngs-MacBookPro:~ young$ conda activate
Youngs-MacBookPro:~ young$
```

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run Conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675907/how-to-run-conda)

Comment: You haven't actually shown that there aren't any changes - just that there isn't `PS1` change. Please add the output from `conda config --show changeps1`. Also, please add either a `which python` or a `conda info` result before and after activation.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
source activate <env-name>
```

`Conda activate` only works on conda 4.6 and later versions.

For conda versions prior to 4.6, type:

Windows: `activate`

Linux and macOS: `source activate`

Ref: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands.html#id2

Answer (score 0):

You need to do conda init with you shell, where the path is configured and then use activate

```
conda init <bash|powershell|tsh|..>
```

Once configure, either close and open your shell or open a new one and use

```
conda activate <env name>
```

Answer (score -1):

Install pip (Python Package Installer):

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

Install virtualenv:

```
sudo pip install virtualenv
```

Create a new virtualenv:

```
virtualenv yourenv -p python3.6
```

***Activate virtualenv:

```
source bin/activate
```