# Why my conda activate does not work though I have a list of conda environments?

Tags: anaconda, conda

I have already created my own environment using conda in linux. When I check `conda info --envs`, it gives a list of environment like

```
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /home1/sriparna/anaconda3
copy_Env_deepgo          /home1/sriparna/anaconda3/envs/copy_Env_deepgo
deepgo_2                 /home1/sriparna/anaconda3/envs/deepgo_2
deepgo_3                 /home1/sriparna/anaconda3/envs/deepgo_3
enzy                     /home1/sriparna/anaconda3/envs/enzy
parth                    /home1/sriparna/anaconda3/envs/parth
protein_struc            /home1/sriparna/anaconda3/envs/protein_struc
py2                      /home1/sriparna/anaconda3/envs/py2
```

But I cant activate a particular environment. e.g. when I tried `conda activate parth` it shows

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.
```

Please help me regarding this.

Comment: @Simba's answer is the best practice, however, it already covered in this possible duplicate: [How to run Conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675907/how-to-run-conda).

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me:

```
source {path_to_anaconda}/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda activate parth
```

Comment: awesome friend,  I was facing the same issue and your point worked for me

Comment: This works in `git bash` on Windows 10 for a current shell session with a path `/c/Program\ Files/Anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh`. To find conda path `conda info | grep -i 'base environment'`

Answer (score 4):

Conda is not initialized in your shell. Run the following commands in an interactive shell,

```sh
conda init
```

Conda will detect the type of your shell, and write init scripts into the shell's configuration file. (Running it once is enough.)

#### Detail

Conda updated its environment activation after 4.6.

[Quote from conda 4.6 release log](https://www.anaconda.com/conda-4-6-release/)

> Conda 4.4 allowed “conda activate envname”. The problem was that setting up your shell to use this new feature was not always straightforward. Conda 4.6 adds extensive initialization support so that more shells than ever before can use the new “conda activate” command. For more information, read the output from “conda init –help”

In previous `conda`, the binaries installed by the default env "base" are exposed into the shell.

After `conda init` is introduced in `conda` 4.6, conda only expose command 
 `conda` into the `PATH`. And environment switch is unified by `conda activate env-name` and `conda deactivate` on all platforms. But to make these commands work, you have to do an additional initialization with `conda init`.

Read the conda 4.6 release log for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I had installed anaconda in Ubuntu VM environment but base was not loading, tried adding the PATH to .bashrc, didn't solve as Conda:not found was error.

Then I solved through:

Press F1>>Terminal: Select Default Profile

You might have available options :

- bash
- fish
- tcsh
- xonsh
- zsh
- powershell

Choose YOUR_SHELL_NAME

Run:

```
eval "$(/home/mishra/anaconda3/bin/conda shell.YOUR_SHELL_NAME hook)"
```

#example

```
 eval "$(/home/mishra/anaconda3/bin/conda shell.bash hook)"
```

Immediately (base) will show