# anaconda activate the system version of python instead of virtual env on Mac

Tags: python, anaconda

I want to activate the anaconda virtual env on the command line.
And I used the commands below to activate it.

```
source activate py368 (or conda activate py368)
(py368) **@** $
```

It seemed the virtual env had been activated, but when I ran python codes, the command line just called the system version of python.

```
(py368) **@** $ python
import sys
sys.executable
```

The output showed that the version of python was not conda virtual env.

```
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6'
```

But I found I can activate the virtual env using the code below, which is quite inconvenient.

```
source /Users/**/anaconda3/bin/activate
conda activate py368
/Users/**/anaconda3/envs/py368/bin/python
```

This method can activate the virtual env as I want.

```
sys.executable
'/Users/**/anaconda3/envs/py368/bin/python'
```

Is there any way to solve the problem to make the activate work fine?

**Update:**

After activating conda virtual env, the virtual env bin folder was added to the PATH, but it still cannot work.

```
$PATH
-bash: `/Users/**/anaconda3/envs/py368/bin:/Users/**/anaconda3/condabin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin: No such file or directory`
```

**Final Solution:**

I found the solution to my problem.
My ~/.bash_profile contains these few sentences, and after commenting them, I can activate the conda virtual env. Then I put `python` in the command, it will call the virtual version of Python. 
But I don't understand why this happened? Just because I changed the system version of Python?

```
#PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"
#export PATH

#alias #python="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run Conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675907/how-to-run-conda) `source activate` is not recommended. Conda has a `conda init` command that will set up your shell (`bash` or others) so you don't have to do `source activate`. Recommended initialization is `conda activate`.

Comment: @merv, the virtual env path is in the PATH, but it doesn't work. And I tried `conda activate`, still not work.