# Unable to Download Python 3.7, 64-bit graphic on Catalina, Macbook Pro (2017)

Tags: python, anaconda

My 2017 Macbook pro recently crashed when trying to download Catalina. I brought the machine in to the store, they wiped the drive and installed Catalina. Have been trying to install Python 3.7, 64-bit graphic installer for 2 days, but it is not recognized. Have tried all local disks.

input and output:

```
~ % conda -V

zsh: command not found: conda
```

Comment: What version of the Anaconda distribution are you trying to install?  The latest (version 2019.10) had an update for Catalina I believe.

Comment: installing _Anaconda3-2019.10-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg_                          I've also tried to uninstall and re-install, no help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run Conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675907/how-to-run-conda). Specifically see using `conda init`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55526573/570918