# jupyter not found even after creating .zshrc file and copying anaconda installer code from bash profile

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter, zsh, zshrc

I've recently updated to macOS 10.15.1 (Catalina) and switched to zsh. I then couldn't launch jupyter notebook from the command line. zsh couldn't find jupyter. There wasn't a zshrc file either. So I created one, added the code below from my bash_profile and saved it. After executing source .zshrc I still get the error - zsh: command not found: jupyter. Where am I going wrong?

```
# added by Anaconda3 2019.03 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
# . "/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"  # commented out by conda initialize
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<
```

Comment: Don't copy the code from `.bash_profile` - that's specific to bash (note the `shell.bash` in the code). Instead run `/anaconda3/bin/conda init zsh` from a zsh session, then restart the session. That is, follow the directions in [How to run Conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675907/how-to-run-conda), specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55526573/570918).