# Conda command not recognised on macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, shell, anaconda, zsh

I installed Anaconda on a new Mac with macOS Catalina, but when I run Conda install commands, `conda` is not found

`zsh: command not found: conda`

I did some research and installed from .sh according to [this Anaconda blog post](https://www.anaconda.com/how-to-restore-anaconda-after-macos-catalina-update/) but it still failed on me.

Comment: Duplicate: [How to run Conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675907/how-to-run-conda) Specifically see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55526573/570918).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it took me a bit of searching around to find the correct sequence of steps. Since my default shell was already zsh, I had to open a bash shell to run `conda init zsh`.

Check out https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208050 and follow the steps in *How to use a different shell without changing the default*

Once I figured that out and changed Terminal back to use the default shell `conda` worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved creating a .zshrc file on Users/my_user/ 
You can use nano on your terminal to do that `nano ~/.zshrc` then add a reference to your .bash_profile where you have your conda path `source ~/.bash_profile`. That worked for me.

Apparently macOs Catalina uses zsh instead bash. You can find some info in the next link: [Why does MacOS Catalina use Zsh instead of Bash?](https://thenextweb.com/dd/2019/06/04/why-does-macos-catalina-use-zsh-instead-of-bash-licensing/)

Comment: what should I include in the .zshrc file and how could I reference the bash_profile

Comment: In the .zshrc file include the next line `source ~/.bash_profile`. That should works.

Comment: Works but is really a winded way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize conda for your shell (as opposed to sourcing bash profile from inside zsh):

```
conda init zsh
```

This should add the relevant lines to your zshrc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still using bash as your terminal you need to know the location of two files.  The first is your .bash_profile and the second is the location of the Conda application.  For me, using OSX Catalina, the Conda application is located in

```
/usr/local/anaconda3/condabin
```

You could check to see where they are doing the following:

Open Terminal:

You should be able to see your .bash_profile there using:

```
ls -la
```

Your .bash_profile should be in this home directory, which is normally opened up with terminal.

```
cd /usr/local/anaconda3/condabin/
```

Should be the location of your Conda Application.  If it is not there you may have to grep for it.  That is how I found it. Using:

## Searches everywhere

```
egrep --color -R 'conda' *
```

and then going through the list.

use a program like vi or gedit and update your .bash_profile to include a new path. Open it and add the following:

```
 export PATH=/usr/local/anaconda3/condabin/:$PATH
```

or

```
export PATH=/<Folder that contains Conda>/:$PATH
```

If this does not work for you please see:

https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/10998