# source activate env_name command failed

Tags: shell, conda

I want to run this code:

```
#! /bin/sh

env_name="base"
source activate $env_name
```

in my shell as `sh filename.sh`, but an error say:

```
filename.sh: source: not found
```

with the following line:

```
filename.sh: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

what is the problem? It is good to say that I can run this command in shell manually but when I try to run as shell script this problem gives me the error. any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

### Options

You have three options:

1. **Login Mode** - use a shell in login mode that automatically sets up Conda's shell functionality.
2. **Manual initialization** - where you manually source the shell-appropriate initialization script to enable `conda activate` functionality in your script.
3. **`conda run`** - where you let Conda auto-activate the env for you.

---

#### 1: Login Mode

Typical Conda installations have users run `conda init` for their primary shell, which adds code to the user's shell-specific resource file (e.g., `.bashrc`). The current way OP runs the script, and the script's shebang, will never load such a resource and therefore do not define the `conda activate` function.

Instead, redefine the shebang to use a full shell and run in login mode. For example, this would be the BASH version:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash -l
```

and run with either

```bash
. filename.sh
```

or

```bash
bash -l filename.sh
```

This assumes the user has run `conda init bash`.

---

#### 2: Manual Initialization

The `conda activate` functionality is normally a shell function that Conda creates at the start up of your interactive shells. To use this same functionality in scripts, you can manually run the initialization script. Assuming a `bash` type shell, this is located under the base Anaconda/Miniconda directory at `etc/profile.d/conda.sh`. Let's assume you have it at:

```
/Users/user/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
```

A working version of your script would then go something like

```
#!/bin/sh

. /Users/user/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda activate base

...
```

---

#### 3: Conda Run

You can use `conda run` (see `conda run --help`) in the shebang to automatically activate the env and run everything in the script in that context. This assumes that you have [properly configured your shell to use `conda`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55526573/570918).  For example,

```
#!/usr/bin/env conda run -n base bash

some_cmd
```

where `some_cmd` is a commandline program that is available in your env.

Answer (score 0):

There is no command named `source` in POSIX shell. To source a file, use a period, i.e.

```
. filename.sh
```