# Which command returns multiple installation paths: how to manage them?

Tags: python, bash, shell, conda

When I run `which` command in the terminal, I sometimes get multiples return values. Eg:

```
python est ~/miniconda3/envs/mikado2/bin/python
python est ~/miniconda3/bin/python
python est /usr/bin/python
```

So my question is: how to manage these installations ? Which one is the one by default and how to change it ?

More generally, when I use a conda environment, I thought I would have access in priority the one installed in the conda environment, but it does seem to be so straight-forward.    How do you handle conda tools versions when you have both these tools installed locally and with conda ?

Answer (score 0):

If you [set up Conda using `conda init`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55526573/570918), then you should never have two Conda Pythons on the PATH simultaneously. Since `conda activate` prepends to PATH, any system-level installations should be superseded.

I have seen others have issues when different Python installations have identical major.minor versions (e.g., 3.6 + 3.6), and experience a leakage of packages from the system-level Python into the Conda Python. I've tested this with the Mac OS X (it has Python 2.7.16 at `/usr/bin/python`) and a matching env, and find that with the env activated, the Conda Python takes priority and I cannot load any packages that are only present in the system-level Python. Checking `import sys; print(sys.path)` can also reveal whether the Python is staying isolated.

I suspect those experiencing leakage issues have installed separate system- or user-level installs of Python that may have included setting `PYTHONPATH`, which definitely leads to leakage and typically should be avoided.