# Installing a Python environment with Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, homebrew

I have just tried to install Anaconda using Home-brew using the terminal, and receive the following message:

```
L-MBP:agda-stdlib le$ brew install conda 
Updating Homebrew...
Error: No available formula with the name "conda"

==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow
Error: No previously deleted formula found.

==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.

==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.

L-MBP:agda-stdlib le$ brew install anaconda
Error: No available formula with the name "anaconda" 
Found a cask named "anaconda" instead. Try
  brew cask install anaconda``

L-MBP:agda-stdlib le$ brew cask install anaconda
==> Caveats
Cask anaconda installs files under /usr/local. The presence of such
files can cause warnings when running `brew doctor`, which is considered
to be a bug in Homebrew Cask.
...
installation finished.
==> Changing ownership of paths required by anaconda; your password may be necessary
  anaconda was successfully installed!

L-MBP:agda-stdlib le$ conda create --name snakes python=3.7.2
-bash: conda: command not found
L-MBP:agda-stdlib le$ conda -bash: conda: command not found
```

When I try to open anaconda and when I try to make a Python environment, I receive the message ''command not found''.

What is the problem?

Comment: What happen when you try conda --version  ?

Comment: ``-bash: conda: command not found``

Comment: Are you typing the commands in anaconda prompt or in  CMD ?

Comment: In a Mac terminal.

Comment: I am sorry I just realize that there is not anaconda prompt in macOS

Comment: try restart the terminal?

Comment: @IvanWiryadi This doesn't work.

Comment: Have you looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55526573/570918)? That is, find the `anaconda/bin/conda`, next run `<path>/anaconda/bin/conda init`, then restart the shell.

Comment: This line in the brew installation is probably the biggest clue to the answer: "==> Changing ownership of paths required by anaconda; your password may be necessary"

Check out my answer below -- it will tell you how to put anaconda in your PATH.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Install anaconda via Homebrew**

Install anaconda via `brew cask` by executing

```
➜ brew cask install anaconda   (or)
➜ brew install --cask anaconda [Newer versions of Homebrew]
.
.
.
PREFIX=/usr/local/anaconda3
.
.
.
  anaconda was successfully installed!
```

**Let’s run jupyter notebook**

Try to executing `jupyter notebook` in your terminal.

It’s not works … why? Because our shell doesn’t know where is the anaconda folder so is, let’s add that folder to our shell path.

**Setup the environment path.**

Insert a line below on top of your  `~/.zshrc` file because when you trying to execute python on terminal it’ll search on folder /usr/local/anaconda3/bin first before search on default operating system path which means you can execute jupyter notebook and python .

```
export PATH="/usr/local/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

Restart terminal or use `source ~/.zshrc` to reload your shell environment and execute jupyter notebook an output will be like this

[image: terminal]

Reference: [Install anaconda on macOS with Homebrew](https://medium.com/ayuth/install-anaconda-on-macos-with-homebrew-c94437d63a37)

Comment: Seems homebrew puts anaconda at `/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/bin/`

Comment: `/usr/local/anaconda3` path did not working anymore

Answer (score 3):

To install Anaconda using Homebrew:

1. Go to your terminal and type `brew cask install anaconda`, then hit return.
2. Make sure that anaconda is in your `PATH`. You'll need to open your terminal's configuration file (usually this is `~/.zshrc` on a mac) and find the line that starts `PATH=`. Add a line nearby that says: `export PATH="/usr/local/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"`. This is where Homebrew installs Anaconda.
3. Quit and restart your terminal. This is the easiest way to make sure that the new configuration will be loaded.
4. Test whether it's working  with `which conda`.

You should now be able to use the `conda` command.

EDIT: As similar posts in this topic have pointed out, the way `conda activate` works has changed from version to version. If the above isn't giving you good enough results, try the following method to enable the `conda activate` and `conda deactivate` commands.

For bash or zsh, putting

`export PATH="/opt/conda/bin:$PATH"`

in your ~/.zshrc file puts your base environment on PATH, but doesn't necessarily actually activate that environment. Try removing that line and replacing it with

```
. ~/Anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda activate base
```

as recommended in the [official Anaconda 4.4.0 release notes](https://github.com/conda/conda/releases/tag/4.4.0).

Replace `~/Anaconda3` with the path where you installed Anaconda, if you put it somewhere else.

Running `conda activate base` puts the base environment on PATH and gives you access to the executables in the base environment.

**Additional Resources:**

- Anaconda and JetBrains have a partnership. You can download the PyCharm IDE with Homebrew: `brew cask install pycharm-ce-with-anaconda-plugin`. [Here is the link to the tap](https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/pycharm-ce-with-anaconda-plugin#default).
- [Official Anaconda documentation on installing for MacOS](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/mac-os/)
- [Link to the canonical Homebrew cask for Anaconda](https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/anaconda#default)
- [Official Anaconda 4.4.0 Release Notes](https://github.com/conda/conda/releases/tag/4.4.0)

Comment: I read this article but unfortunately the instructions did not work.  However I found that homebrew had placed my anaconda3 installation under a different path.  Adding the following seemed to work.  I'm hoping this helps someone out.

export PATH="/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"

Answer (score 0):

Timothy Chan's answer seemed to work best.

After installation of Anaconda through homebrew, put the following into your terminal.

export PATH="/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"

You can now open a Jupyter notebook and do other things but keep in mind that you will have to run the above command every time for now. Will try to find a fix for this :)

Answer (score 0):

```bash
brew install --cask anaconda
/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/bin/conda init zsh
source ~/.zshrc
```

https://gist.github.com/x1wins/ccf1686b8916c24438e109f585c9fb5d
When I install anaconda with brew, conda did not working in terminal.
I found this command `conda init zsh` instead of `add path`