# How to only use anaconda python when needed (in linux)

Tags: python, linux, anaconda

I wanted to use anaconda python in Linux without adding it to path (I don't want to set is as default python).

I used to simply set an alias for commands that I use in .bashrc like `alias condapython="~/anaconda3/bin/python"`. This is sometimes hard to use!

So I'm looking for another way. What I need is a command to run whenever I need to use anaconda.

Can I for example run `source ~/anaconda3/bin/activate`? I mean, is anaconda python nothing more than a virtual environment?
Or you suggest something else?

Comment: _I wanted to use anaconda python in Linux without adding it to path (I don't want to set is as default python)._ Don't you have that option when installing Anaconda?

Comment: @AMC I have, but after that, how can I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a default install, follow [the directions on using `conda init`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55526573/570918) to configure your shell to use Conda. Then disable auto-activation of the **base** environment:

```bash
conda config —-set auto_activate_base false
```

This will let you use the system-level Python installation by default. You can use `conda activate <env_name>` to activate environments, or simply `conda activate` for the **base** environment.

Comment: Thanks. it looks when anaconda environment is not activated, the only extra thing is path is just conda command.