# How activate conda environment on demand in macOS zsh Terminal session?

Tags: anaconda, conda, zsh, oh-my-zsh

This is under macOS Big Sur 11.1, with zsh as the shell (and oh-my-zsh) after a new Anaconda 3 installation.

Since I do *not* always want to be using the conda/anaconda python distribution to be used (sometimes I want to be using MacPorts python), in the base environment I executed command:

```
conda config --set auto_activate_base False
```

How do I activate the conda base configuration in a Terminal session "on demand", now that the `conda` command is no longer automatically available there?

Comment: the `conda activate` command should still be there. Did you run `conda init zsh`?

Comment: Since there is no `conda` command available in zsh at present (after conda config --set auto_activate_base False), I cannot do conda init zsh.

Comment: Locate the binary, run `conda init zsh`, then restart your shell session. This will add `conda activate` as a shell command to all your interactive `zsh` sessions. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55526573/570918

Comment: OK, I ran `source /opt/anaconda3/bin/activate`; then `conda init zsh`; then `conda config --set auto_activate_base False`. Now my original question remains: how do I (easily) get the conda base config in a zsh Terminal session?

Comment: `conda activate` will activate the **base** environment.