# Using default version of python on windows?

Tags: python, windows, anaconda

I recently installed the Anaconda version of Python. Now when I type python into the terminal it opens the Anaconda distribution rather than the default distribution. How do I get it to use the default version for the command python on windows? I have added the distribution to the path but when i type python --version, it shows the conda version and not the system version.

Comment: Almost any installation assumes that you want this new version to be the default; the installation program sets the system PATH variable to include the new on before any others.  You need to edit your PATH variable to the search ordering you want.  Look up how to do that.  Also research "Python wrong version".

Answer (score 1):

Conda manipulates the `PATH` variable when it activates environments. A default install will auto-activate the **base** environment, which results in giving it precedence over other software accessible from `PATH`. If you would prefer Conda not to auto-activate **base** by default, then set this in the configuration:

```bash
conda config --set auto_activate_base false
```

**Documentation**

```bash
$ conda config --describe auto_activate_base
# # auto_activate_base (bool)
# #   Automatically activate the base environment during shell
# #   initialization.
# # 
# auto_activate_base: true
```

Otherwise, one can always do an *ad hoc* deactivation with `conda deactivate`. This latter operation assumes [the Conda shell functions are initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55526573/570918).