# Miniconda3 installed on WSL2: conda command not found

Tags: conda, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed WSL2 on Windows 10 and then installed miniconda3 from the Ubuntu shell with:

```bash
sudo sh Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

When I try to use Conda from the bash it says:

```
conda: command not found
```

I added a picture of my `$PATH`. Did anyone else encounter the same problem? How to fix it?

[image: $PATH]
[miniconda_installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPukE.png)
[miniconda_directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIv3e.png)

Comment: First, don't use `sudo` - that should only be used by sys admins (people who manage multiple users). Second, instructions are here: [How to run Conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675907/how-to-run-conda) But generally, default install covers all this. You basically just need to locate the binary manually once (usually under `bin/` or `/condabin` where you installed `miniconda3`, then run `conda init` and restart the shell session.

Comment: @merv : thank you so much for your reply. I solved adding the string: export PATH=~/miniconda3/bin:$PATH to the bashrc file.

Comment: that is an outdated solution and not recommended because it violates isolation of environments. Instead, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55526573/570918) tracks the best practice recommendations.