# How to set a "SHELL" to use Conda activate

Tags: python, conda

I have been given a guide to install tensorflow, keras and sciann, but my python fails and cannot google why. I have an old 2010 MacBook Pro (masOS 10.12.6) and I use Python 3.8.5 via Spyder. This is what do:

First, I create an environment ”ml” with python:

```
conda create -n ml python=3.8.5 -y
```

This works I have ckecked the folder on my computer. Then I try to activate this

```
conda activate ml
```

And this is where I get error:

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.



Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

I also tried `condo init ml` without any luck. I have really tried to google but all the solution I find won't help. Can you help me manage around? I don't know what a shell is and what shell I should use.

Comment: You run `conda init bash` once, then restart your terminal session. Duplicate: [How to run Conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675907/how-to-run-conda)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your terminal, enter the following command:

```
ps -p $$
```

to figure out what shell you have. A shell basically allows you access to the operating system of your computer. Then, based on what it says, do conda init. For example, if it says bash, then do:

```
 conda init bash
```

conda init bash is basically telling your computer that you can launch the conda program from your shell. In this case, your shell is "bash", which is one of the many different shells.

Comment: Arh! so I just needed to type all these in there terminal and not Spyder. This seems to work! THANKS!