# Error using NCO in Jupyter Notebook not loading, gives error TypeError, after correctly (I think) installing Pynco

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conda, nco

I am trying to convert an hdf5 file to NetCDF using nco. I have properly installed Pynco and nco into my conda environment as called below (seperate, not my base env) from bash shell:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pynco
```

When I try to call and import the packages into my Jupyter Notebook using

```
from nco import Nco
nco = Nco()
```

I get the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-ce3bb555a308> in <module>
      8 import scipy
      9 from nco import Nco
---> 10 nco = Nco()

~/anaconda3/envs/aoes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nco/nco.py in __init__(self, returnCdf, return_none_on_error, force_output, cdf_module, debug, **kwargs)
     56             self.nco_path = os.environ["NCOpath"]
     57         else:
---> 58             self.nco_path = os.path.split(distutils.spawn.find_executable("ncks"))[0]
     59 
     60         self.operators = operators

~/anaconda3/envs/aoes/lib/python3.6/posixpath.py in split(p)
    105     """Split a pathname.  Returns tuple "(head, tail)" where "tail" is
    106     everything after the final slash.  Either part may be empty."""
--> 107     p = os.fspath(p)
    108     sep = _get_sep(p)
    109     i = p.rfind(sep) + 1

TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

I researched and saw that I may need to add a PATH to my environment pointing to NCO but not totally sure how to do that. I know I have a PATH variable added to my .bashrc file in my home linux environment for anaconda, do I add something there?

More info for my setup: Output from `conda list nco`:

```
# packages in environment at /home/jcamp/anaconda3/envs/aoes:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
nco                       5.0.0                hf82150d_0    conda-forge
pynco                     1.0.0                      py_1    conda-forge
webencodings              0.5.1                      py_1    conda-forge
```

Section of .bashrc file with path variables (no difference with or without Ncopath line - although I'm pretty sure my path is wrong for this):

```
export PATH="/home/jcamp/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
export NCOpath="../usr/local/bin:$NCOpath"
```

I launch jupyter notebook through a virtual environment and creating a ipkernyl for access through a secure portal. I had no issues installing and utilizing 20+ packages with my current environment. NCO is the first one to cause issues.

With my environment active, `which ncks` produces:

```
/home/jcamp/anaconda3/envs/aoes/bin/ncks
```

Comment: Works for me: `conda create -n nco python=3.6 pynco ipykernel` I.e., shouldn't need to do anything extra to work. Consider adding: 1) output from `conda list nco` 2) section from `.bashrc` where you manipulate PATH 3) describe how you launch Jupyter and registered the `aoes` environment as a kernel 4) verify when env is activate that `which ncks` finds the binary. Also, please see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55526573/570918

Comment: Merv, I added additional info per your comments in main body.