# CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'. Mac M1 Apple Silicon Miniforge

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda

I am trying to install miniforge to use it with tensorflow. I am using MacOS Monterrey.

**Recreating The Issue**

```
$ /Users/sarangpark/miniforge3/bin/conda init zsh

no change     /Users/sarangpark/opt/anaconda3/condabin/conda
no change     /Users/sarangpark/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda
no change     /Users/sarangpark/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda-env
no change     /Users/sarangpark/opt/anaconda3/bin/activate
no change     /Users/sarangpark/opt/anaconda3/bin/deactivate
no change     /Users/sarangpark/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
no change     /Users/sarangpark/opt/anaconda3/etc/fish/conf.d/conda.fish
no change     /Users/sarangpark/opt/anaconda3/shell/condabin/Conda.psm1
no change     /Users/sarangpark/opt/anaconda3/shell/condabin/conda-hook.ps1
no change     /Users/sarangpark/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xontrib/conda.xsh
no change     /Users/sarangpark/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.csh
no change     /Users/sarangpark/.zshrc
No action taken.

$ exec zsh -l

$ /Users/sarangpark/miniforge3/bin/conda activate env_tensorflow3

CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.
```

I also have anaconda installed so using the `conda` command creates a virtual env with anaconda.
(And Anaconda doesn't work because installing tensorflow doesn't work)

Comment: Please help otherwise I have to resort to using Google Collab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
/Users/sarangpark/miniforge3/bin/conda activate
```

The point of `conda init` is to add shell code to the shell initialization file in order to define a shell function `conda` that serves as a wrapper over the Python entry point (`/Users/sarangpark/miniforge3/bin/conda`). There are details [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69024715/570918).

You can check that `conda` is properly defined with the `type` function. For example, in my `zsh`, I see:

```bash
% type conda
conda is a shell function from /Users/mfansler/.zshrc
```

If that works, then you should be fine with

```bash
conda activate env_tensorflow3
```

Also, be sure your shell is actually `zsh`. MacOS default is usually to have `%` delimit the prompt in `zsh`, and has `$` for `bash`.

Answer (score 1):

Try typing the following command in your terminal:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Then try activating your environment.