# Creating environment in miniconda on Mac M1

Tags: python-3.x, apple-m1, miniconda, rosetta-2

I recently got a new Mac with M1 processor. From the terminal I installed miniconda through home-brew. Then, I tried to create a new conda environment as usual using `conda create --name my_env`. Then, I try to activate the environment using `conda activate my_env`, but I get the following error:

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.
```

I obey of course, and I run `conda init bash` and close and restart my shell. However, when I then try to activate my environment I receive the above error again (and rerunning `conda init bash` does not fix the problem because it simply says 'no action taken'.

Questions:

1. Does anyone know why I still can't run `conda activate`?
2. Is it smart to even use miniconda for Python without Rosetta?

Many thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "this doesn't work"? How exactly does it "not work"?

Comment: Well, even after configuring my shell to bash I am unable to run `conda activate`. Changed the question.

Comment: Are you sure your shell is BASH? AFAIK, macOS switched to zsh be default

Comment: Ah using zsh works! Thanks so much!

Comment: Proposed duplicate: [How to run Conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675907/how-to-run-conda) Namely, see answer on `conda init` which documents using `zsh` for MacOS 10.15+.

Answer (score 1):

Mac changed the shell from Bash to Zsh a couple years ago. So, you need to do

> conda init zsh