# How to activate base env on conda prompt

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

Conda works as expected and activates the base env on every new installation when I run conda in my miniconda prompt. However, it does not activate the base env anymore at when I rerun after installation, I have added paths to system environment and conda activate doesn't work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run Conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675907/how-to-run-conda)

Answer (score 0):

Don't add miniconda/python.exe to the path. It won't help you, since more sophisticated packages like **numpy** would also need the paths to the C-libraries. This is exactly what is achieved by **activating an environment** via

```
conda activate
```

in the command shell. (Check PATH before and after.)

For further information read the docs: https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment