# Issue importing Python module even though it exists in my Conda environment

Tags: python, anaconda, pulp

I'm trying to install the [Pulp](https://pypi.org/project/PuLP/) library.
I install in Conda with `python -m pip install pulp` and I have also tried
`conda install -c conda-forge pulp` .

When I do `conda list` I can see it installed but when I try `import pulp` I get `No module named pulp`.
I've tried with clean conda environments and Python 3.8 and 3.9. Any help is appreciated.

I activate the environment with
`source activate myconda3`.
Doing `print(sys.executable)` I get

```
usr/local/packages/live/eb/Anaconda3/5.3.0/bin/python'
```

Doing `print(sys.path)` I get

```
['', '/home/sm1epk/USA/datasets/CLM_data', '/usr/local/packages/live/eb/Anaconda3/5.3.0/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/local/packages/live/eb/Anaconda3/5.3.0/lib/python3.7', '/usr/local/packages/live/eb/Anaconda3/5.3.0/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/home/sm1epk/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/packages/live/eb/Anaconda3/5.3.0/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/packages/live/eb/Anaconda3/5.3.0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions', '/home/sm1epk/.ipython']
```

Comment: Please add details showing how you activate the environment, then show output from `import sys; print(sys.executable); print(sys.path)`.

Comment: Thanks for adding those details. It appears your environment ois not activated. The `source activate` syntax is deprecated in favor of `conda activate`. Also, please ensure you are not manually adding your base Anaconda `bin/` directory to PATH. Maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55526573/570918