# SGE batch file not reading .bashrc and conda command not found

Tags: bash, conda, cluster-computing, jobs, qsub

I have multiple `conda` environments working fine. when I try to subit a job using `qsub` to SGE, the `.bashrc` file is not read. The batch script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
#$ -S /bin/bash
#$ -cwd
#$ -l h_cpu=48:00:00
#$ -l h_vmem=2048M
#$ -q pascal@pascal-[0123]-0[01234567]
## allocate the number of cores:
#$ -pe mpi 1
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4

conda activate my_env
python ./test.py
```

I am getting the error: `conda: Command not found.`
Also, it can't find bash commands like `export`.

`source ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.bash_profile`  does not help.

If I use `qsub -V ....`, the code somehow runs but it says

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.
```

However, I do not want to use `qsub -V` because of some external reasons.

I am new to this cluster, so I am clueless. I just want to be able to choose freely between different `conda enviroments` in the batch script. Please help.

**Edit 1: after seeing the comment**

```
#!/bin/bash -l
#$ -cwd
#$ -l h_cpu=48:00:00
#$ -l h_vmem=2048M
#$ -q pascal@pascal-[0123]-0[01234567]
## allocate the number of cores:
#$ -pe mpi 1
setenv OMP_NUM_THREADS 1

conda activate my_env
python ./test.py
```

gives me `conda: Command not found.`

Comment: As per duplicate, using `#!/bin/bash -l` for shebang should cover it. But I consider `conda run` preferable for programmatic execution in an environment context. E.g., `conda run -n my_env --live-stream python test.py`

Comment: Neither work for me.

Comment: @merv Neither works for me.

Comment: Then your shell isn't initialized (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55526573/570918). I.e., run `/full/path/to/bin/conda init bash` *once* in an interactive session.

Comment: `conda init ...` within the batch script messed up all my previous envs, had to sort things manually, nightmare. What seems to work now:
`export PATH="/path/to/conda/bin:$PATH"`

`eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)"` and then `conda activate my_env`

Comment: More fundamentally, understand that `qsub` jobs do not run an interactive shell. If there are shell setup routines you want to use from both interactive and noninteractive shell instances, probably move those to a separate file which you `source` both from your `.bash_profile` and from any script which needs those settings. This is a common FAQ.

Comment: On PBS jobs, I could switch between conda envs easily within the script.

Comment: No one should recommend to run `conda init` in a batch script. Run once per user in interactive session...done. Clean up the user `.bashrc` (or `.bash_profile`) if you encounter issues.

Comment: @tripleee does `qsub` not respect shebang `bash -l`? LSF and SLURM certainly do.

Comment: Cleaner is `eval "$(/path/to/conda/bin/conda shell.bash hook)"`. No need to manually add to PATH.

Comment: `bash -l` runs a login shell, which reads `.bash_profile`, not `.bashrc`. It's not clear from the exposition which of these files contains whatever `conda` initialization the OP requires.

Comment: my .bashrc has the conda initialization part

Comment: So, probably `bash -i`; but again, forcing an interactive shell for a noniteractive task is a pretty crude workaround, and it's probably better to isolate those parts into a separate file you `source` from both places; or indeed, simply copy the `conda` initialization code into scripts which need it.