# Packages available in jupyter but not listed in conda list

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, conda

I am having problems understanding what is happening. I created a conda environment `conda create -name um python=3.9`. Now I should have an empty environment, but after deactivating base and changing environment to um i can run for example `jupyter notebook` and import all the packages (for example pandas, numpy, seaborn). This is output of `conda list` inside um environment:

```
# packages in environment at /home/bartosz/anaconda3/envs/um:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                        main  
_openmp_mutex             5.1                       1_gnu  
ca-certificates           2023.12.12           h06a4308_0  
ld_impl_linux-64          2.38                 h1181459_1  
libffi                    3.4.4                h6a678d5_0  
libgcc-ng                 11.2.0               h1234567_1  
libgomp                   11.2.0               h1234567_1  
libstdcxx-ng              11.2.0               h1234567_1  
ncurses                   6.4                  h6a678d5_0  
openssl                   3.0.13               h7f8727e_0  
pip                       23.3.1           py39h06a4308_0  
python                    3.9.18               h955ad1f_0  
readline                  8.2                  h5eee18b_0  
setuptools                68.2.2           py39h06a4308_0  
sqlite                    3.41.2               h5eee18b_0  
tk                        8.6.12               h1ccaba5_0  
tzdata                    2024a                h04d1e81_0  
wheel                     0.41.2           py39h06a4308_0  
xz                        5.4.6                h5eee18b_0  
zlib                      1.2.13               h5eee18b_0
```

Jupyter, pandas etc is not installed. Can someone explain what is going on? It seems as if i am still in base.

*edit* :

output of `which jupyter`:
`/home/bartosz/anaconda3/bin/jupyter`

Also i noticed that when i create conda environment using: `conda create -n ml anaconda` and run `which jupyter` i get: `/home/bartosz/anaconda3/envs/ml/bin/jupyter`.

Comment: Please edit question to show `which jupyter` to verify from where it is coming. Possibly a user-level installation (i.e., `~/.local/lib/python*/site-packages`) or it could be that somewhere else is on `PATH` that shouldn't be.

Comment: ok, i edited the question and can see now that the path is indeed the problem. How can i fix that?

Comment: The question is, why is `/home/bartosz/anaconda3/bin` on your PATH when **base** isn't activated? It should never be unless doing something substandard like adding it to PATH in `.bashrc` (or `.bash_profile`, etc.) - check them. Or some terminals (e.g., `tmux`) mess with PATH in weird ways. As for the **ml** environment, the `anaconda` superpackage includes *hundreds* of packages, including `jupyter` and `jupyterlab`.

Comment: thank you, this was the issue. For some reason i had a line: export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH in my ~/.bashrc file. Deleting this line has fixed my problem

Comment: Glad you got it figured out! There is unfortunately a lot of residual noise about this topic, since manually adding to PATH was common (even standard) ~7 years ago. E.g., it's hard to put a dent in [an outdated top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35717840/570918) with 400+ upvotes. People have been pointing out the information is bad for 5 years, but only four users have ever downvoted it.